# How to add a progress bar to a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, progress-bar, zsh

When scripting in bash or any other shell in *NIX, while running a command that will take more than a few seconds, a progress bar is needed.

For example, copying a big file, opening a big tar file.

What ways do you recommend to add progress bars to shell scripts?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498304/using-bash-to-display-a-progress-working-indicator for examples of the control logic (background a job and do something until it finishes).

Comment: There is a set of requirements we frequently find useful when scripting. logging, displaying progress, colors, fancy outputs etc... I've always felt there should be some kind of a simple scripting framework. Finally I've decided to implement one since I couldn't find any. You might find this helpful. It is in pure bash, i mean Just Bash. https://github.com/SumuduLansakara/JustBash

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: I like to use `pv` for anything that can be piped. Example: `ssh remote "cd /home/user/ && tar czf - accounts" | pv -s 23091k | tar xz`

Answer (score 798, accepted):

You can implement this by overwriting a line.  Use `\r` to go back to the beginning of the line without writing `\n` to the terminal.

Write `\n` when you're done to advance the line.

Use `echo -ne` to:

1. not print `\n` and
2. to recognize escape sequences like `\r`.

Here's a demo:

```
echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#############             (66%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
echo -ne '\n'
```

In a comment below, puk mentions this "fails" if you start with a long line and then want to write a short line: In this case, you'll need to overwrite the length of the long line (e.g., with spaces).

Comment: According to the **echo** man page (at least on MacOS X) sh/bash use their own built-in **echo** command that doesn't accept "-n" ... so in order to accomplish the same thing you need to put **\r\c** at the end of the string, instead of just **\r**

Comment: I think you mean the Mac version doesn't take -e?  You are right that -e seems to be a GNU extension.

Comment: The portable way to output this is to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: So \r it is. I have to try with MacOS as well

Comment: for printf we would have to use this format: `printf "####   (50%%)\r"`, it wouldn't work with single quotes and percent sign needs to be escaped.

Comment: I don't get this - accepted and heaps of upvotes for a "I'll guess how long this operation will take on unknown hardware" hack? [pv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6863190/37193) is the correct answer IMO (but [bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276265/37193) will do too)

Comment: The question was "How do I do progress bars" with an example of copying files.  I focused on the "graphics" problem, not the calculation of how far along a file copy operation is.

Comment: `echo -n $'#####                     (33%)\r'` works on MacOS X (notice the dollar sign).

Comment: @nurettin You can pass a string as printf's second argument to obviate the need for double quotes and escaped percentage signs: `printf %s"\r" "#####     (50%)"`

Comment: @nurettin: `printf '#### (50%%)\r'` _does_ work with _single_ quotes (the literal `\n` created in the shell string is later expanded by `printf`). Another alternative that doesn't require doubling `%` chars.: `printf %b '#### (50%)\r'` - `%b` tells `printf` to expand control-character escape sequences (only).

Comment: This fails for me if the message is shorter (ie. if you run it in reverse)

Comment: @nurettin, if you're using printf correctly, you pass your data out-of-band from the format string. Something like `printf '% -70s (%s)\n' "####" 30%`, for example, will insert as many spaces needed to have a total of 70 after the `#`s, and will pass the `30%` argument through unmodified/unescaped.

Comment: In case anyone is facing issues with the echo command printing -ne or any other character even when you did not intend to, here's the solution for that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641154/346011

Comment: What if the progress bar goes wider than the screen width `tput cols` and get wrapped? The `\r` does not work in clearing the previous line.

Answer (score 121):

You may also be interested in [how to do a spinner](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/034):

### Can I do a spinner in Bash?

> Sure!
>
> ```
> i=1
> sp="/-\|"
> echo -n ' '
> while true
> do
>     printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
> done
> ```
>
> Each time the loop iterates, it displays the next character in the sp
>   string, wrapping around as it reaches the end. (i is the position of
>   the current character to display and ${#sp} is the length of the sp
>   string).
>
> The \b string is replaced by a 'backspace' character. Alternatively,
>   you could play with \r to go back to the beginning of the line.
>
> If you want it to slow down, put a sleep command inside the loop
>   (after the printf).
>
> A POSIX equivalent would be:
>
> ```
> sp='/-\|'
> printf ' '
> while true; do
>     printf '\b%.1s' "$sp"
>     sp=${sp#?}${sp%???}
> done
> ```
>
> If you already have a loop which does a lot of work, you can call the
>   following function at the beginning of each iteration to update the
>   spinner:
>
> ```
> sp="/-\|"
> sc=0
> spin() {
>    printf "\b${sp:sc++:1}"
>    ((sc==${#sp})) && sc=0
> }
> endspin() {
>    printf "\r%s\n" "$@"
> }
>
> until work_done; do
>    spin
>    some_work ...
> done
> endspin
> ```

Comment: Much shorter version, fully portable*: `while :;do for s in / - \\ \|; do printf "\r$s";sleep .1;done;done` (*: `sleep` may require ints rather than decimals)

Comment: @Daenyth. Thanks. Kindly where we should call the command that we need to watch it is progress using the previous code?

Comment: @goro: In the `some_work ...` line above; a more detailed discussion that builds on this helpful answer and Adam Katz's helpful comment - with a focus on POSIX compliance -  can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38275644/45375).

Comment: @AdamKatz: That's a helpful, portable simplification, but in order to match Daenyth's approach the spinner must be based on `\b` rather than `\r`, as it will otherwise only work at the very beginning of a line: `while :; do for c in / - \\ \|; do printf '%s\b' "$c"; sleep 1; done; done` - or, if displaying the cursor behind the spinner is undesired: `printf ' ' && while :; do for c in / - \\ \|; do printf '\b%s' "$c"; sleep 1; done; done`

Comment: I gave you a spinner, not a progress bar.  Just like this answer.  Progress bars aren't as easily stuffed into a native one-liner unless you're okay with wrapping.

Comment: @AdamKatz great tip. Btw, how to stop this spinner. Meaning, I'm waiting for some long script/command to finish and display this spinner. How to stop it when the long command is finished?

Comment: @kaushal – Ctrl+C will stop it manually. If you have a backgrounded job, you can store its PID (`job=$!`) and then run `while kill -0 $job 2>/dev/null;do …`, for example: `sleep 15 & job=$!; while kill -0 $job 2>/dev/null; do for s in / - \\ \|; do printf "\r$s"; sleep .1; done; done`

Comment: `work_done` is something that you need to describe what it is because it has no reference... i think this code has been copied from other answer because the other answer has similar code but included the `work_done` function.

Comment: @AdamKatz: need space between ! and ;

Comment: @pidloop – That was not my experience in zsh or bash, and since `$!` is a variable that expands to the process ID of the most recently backgrounded job and `;` delimits commands, I don't see a problem in any posix shell.

Comment: Curious. My bash on macOS thinks the ! refers to a history entry.

Comment: @AdamKatz About simplicity and flexibility, try this: `shapes=(. o O);echo -n progress... .;while ! read -t .25 _;do printf '\e[D%s' ${shapes[(cnt++)%${#shapes[@]}]};done;echo $cnt` (end with *`return`*), then try using *UTF8 braille*: `printf -v shapes "%b " \\U28{01,08,10,20,80,40,04,02};shapes=($shapes)`. About *backgrounded process*, have a look at bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298090/1765658) *`sha1Progress`* sample.

Answer (score 81):

Got an easy progress bar function that i wrote the other day:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1. Create ProgressBar function
# 1.1 Input is currentState($1) and totalState($2)
function ProgressBar {
# Process data
    let _progress=(${1}*100/${2}*100)/100
    let _done=(${_progress}*4)/10
    let _left=40-$_done
# Build progressbar string lengths
    _fill=$(printf "%${_done}s")
    _empty=$(printf "%${_left}s")

# 1.2 Build progressbar strings and print the ProgressBar line
# 1.2.1 Output example:                           
# 1.2.1.1 Progress : [########################################] 100%
printf "\rProgress : [${_fill// /#}${_empty// /-}] ${_progress}%%"

}

# Variables
_start=1

# This accounts as the "totalState" variable for the ProgressBar function
_end=100

# Proof of concept
for number in $(seq ${_start} ${_end})
do
    sleep 0.1
    ProgressBar ${number} ${_end}
done
printf '\nFinished!\n'
```

Or snag it from,
https://github.com/fearside/ProgressBar/

Comment: can you explain the line under 1.2.1.1 please? Are you performing a sed substitution with the _fill and _empty variables? I'm confused.

Comment: Instead of using sed, im using bash internal "Substring Replacement", since this is an easy job, i prefer to use the internal functions of bash for this kind of work. Code looks nicer aswell. :-) Check here http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html and search for substring replacement.

Comment: and ${_fill} is assigned as ${_done} number of spaces. This is beautiful. Great job man. I'm definitely going to use this in all my bash scripts haha

Comment: Great work @fearside !  I did a little tweak to skip when _progress did not change from the last value, to improve speed. https://github.com/enobufs/bash-tools/blob/master/bin/progbar

Comment: Sweet. Changing dash by rectangle gives it a more professional look and feel : `printf "\rProgress : [${_fill// /▇}${_empty// / }] ${_progress}%%"`

Comment: Avoid useless forks!! Use `printf -v _fill "%${_done}s"` instead of `_fill=$(printf "%${_done}s")` !

Comment: You can avoid the whole "replacing spaces with filled characters" and just start out by creating a string of characters: `printf -v _fill "#%.0s" $(seq 1 $done)`.

Comment: Would love to use this in AIX KSH I have converted it and everything works except the 
printf "\rProgress : [${_fill// /#}${_empty// /-}] ${_progress}%%" part
How do I write that in ksh? I keep getting errors : The specified substitution is not valid for this command...

Comment: I managed to get the result as
Progress : [                                                 #-] 100%

Answer (score 62):

Use the Linux command [`pv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html).

It doesn't know the size if it's in the middle of the pipeline, but it gives a speed and total, and from there you can figure out how long it should take and get feedback so you know it hasn't hung.

Answer (score 53):

I was looking for something more sexy than the selected answer, so did my own script.

#### Preview

[image: progress-bar.sh in action]

#### Source

I put it on [github `progress-bar.sh`](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/progress-bar.sh)

```
progress-bar() {
  local duration=${1}


    already_done() { for ((done=0; done<$elapsed; done++)); do printf "▇"; done }
    remaining() { for ((remain=$elapsed; remain<$duration; remain++)); do printf " "; done }
    percentage() { printf "| %s%%" $(( (($elapsed)*100)/($duration)*100/100 )); }
    clean_line() { printf "\r"; }

  for (( elapsed=1; elapsed<=$duration; elapsed++ )); do
      already_done; remaining; percentage
      sleep 1
      clean_line
  done
  clean_line
}
```

#### Usage

```
 progress-bar 100
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is integrated into some processing where the length of the process is not known. How to stop progress bar if my process finished earlier, e.g. for unzipping a file.

Comment: I think usage should be `progress-bar 100`

Comment: Attractive progress indeed. How can it be tied to a function that processes prolonged action on remote servers over ssh? I mean how is it possible to measure the timing of an upgrade (for instance) on remote servers?

Comment: @faceless it's not in the scope of this code you provide the time and it count down

Comment: Is `▇` character safe to use? Provided we will use our progressbar across all the most used OS and shells.

Comment: @Fusion it's a unicode character (U+2587 LOWER SEVEN EIGHTHS BLOCK) that should be safe for modern shell. Give it a try on your envs

Comment: @Édouard Lopez How can I stop it if the process finished faster then expected

Comment: @RajeshHatwar You can't without acrobatics. It's just pretty timer, not a progress bar.

Answer (score 52):

Some posts have showed how to display the command's progress.  In order to calculate it, you'll need to see how much you've progressed.  On BSD systems some commands, such as *dd*(1),  accept a `SIGINFO` signal, and will report their progress.  On Linux systems some commands will respond similarly to `SIGUSR1`.  If this facility is available, you can pipe your input through _dd to monitor the number of bytes processed.

Alternatively, you can use [*lsof*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) to obtain the offset of the file's read pointer, and thereby calculate the progress.
Here is an example of using *lsof*(1) to see the progress of *wc*(1) reading a large file named `blob`.

```
$ wc -l blob &
[1] 3405769

$ lsof -w -o0 -o -c wc
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE       OFFSET     NODE NAME
[...]
wc      3405769  dds    3r   REG   254,7 0t2656059392  7733716 blob
```

I've written a command, named [*pmonitor*](https://github.com/dspinellis/pmonitor), that displays the progress of processing a specified process or file.  With it you can do things, such as the following.

```bash
$ pmonitor -c gzip
/home/dds/data/mysql-2015-04-01.sql.gz 58.06%
```

An earlier version of Linux and FreeBSD shell scripts appears on [my blog](http://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20081027) ("Monitor Process Progress on Unix").

Comment: This is awesome, I always forget to pipe things through pv :-) I think my "stat" command works a bit differently, my (Linux) version of this script: https://gist.github.com/unhammer/b0ab6a6aa8e1eeaf236b

Comment: Please, quote the relevant parts of the code in your answer as requested per this help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @cpm I quoted the link's title. If you think something else is needed, then please be more specific.

Comment: "Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible." This answer, while somewhat helpful, doesn't provide a solution unless the link is opened. I'd say it'd be relevant to add the `lsof -w -o0 -o -c command` line and maybe a quick explanation of what it does or how to read the output.

Answer (score 34):

Haven't seen anything similar and all custom functions here seem to focus on rendering alone so... my very simple POSIX compliant solution below with step by step explanations because this question isn't trivial.

### TL;DR

Rendering the progress bar is very easy. Estimating how much of it should render is a different matter. This is how to render (animate) the progress bar - you can copy&paste this example to a file and run it:

```
#!/bin/sh

BAR='####################'   # this is full bar, e.g. 20 chars

for i in {1..20}; do
    echo -ne "\r${BAR:0:$i}" # print $i chars of $BAR from 0 position
    sleep .1                 # wait 100ms between "frames"
done
```

- `{1..20}` - values from 1 to 20
- `echo` - print to terminal (i.e. to `stdout`)
- `echo -n` - print without new line at the end
- `echo -e` - interpret special characters while printing
- `"\r"` - carriage return, a special char to return to the beginning of the line

You can make it render any content at any speed so this method is very universal, e.g. often used for visualization of "hacking" in silly movies, no kidding.

### Full answer (from zero to working example)

The meat of the problem is how to determine the `$i` value, i.e. how much of the progress bar to display. In the above example I just let it increment in `for` loop to illustrate the principle but a real life application would use an infinite loop and calculate the `$i` variable on each iteration. To make said calculation it needs the following ingredients:

1. how much work there is to be done
2. how much work has been done so far

In case of `cp` it needs the size of a source file and the size of the target file:

```
#!/bin/sh

src="/path/to/source/file"
tgt="/path/to/target/file"

cp "$src" "$tgt" &                     # the & forks the `cp` process so the rest
                                       # of the code runs without waiting (async)

BAR='####################'

src_size=$(stat -c%s "$src")           # how much there is to do

while true; do
    tgt_size=$(stat -c%s "$tgt")       # how much has been done so far
    i=$(( $tgt_size * 20 / $src_size ))
    echo -ne "\r${BAR:0:$i}"
    if [ $tgt_size == $src_size ]; then
        echo ""                        # add a new line at the end
        break;                         # break the loop
    fi
    sleep .1
done
```

- `foo=$(bar)` - run `bar` in a subprocess and save its `stdout` to `$foo`
- `stat` - print file stats to `stdout`
- `stat -c` - print a formatted value
- `%s` - format for total size

In case of operations like file unpacking, calculating the source size is slightly more difficult but still as easy as getting the size of an uncompressed file:

```
#!/bin/sh
src_size=$(gzip -l "$src" | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

- `gzip -l` - print info about zip archive
- `tail -n1` - work with 1 line from the bottom
- `tr -s ' '` - translate multiple spaces into one ("squeeze" them)
- `cut -d' ' -f3` - cut 3rd space-delimited field (column)

Here's the meat of the problem I mentioned before. This solution is less and less general. All calculations of the actual progress are tightly bound to the domain you're trying to visualize, is it a single file operation, a timer countdown, a rising number of files in a directory, operation on multiple files, etc., therefore, it can't be reused. The only reusable part is progress bar rendering. To reuse it you need to abstract it and save in a file (e.g. `/usr/lib/progress_bar.sh`), then define functions that calculate input values specific to your domain. This is how a generalized code could look like (I also made the `$BAR` dynamic because people were asking for it, the rest should be clear by now):

```
#!/bin/bash

BAR_length=50
BAR_character='#'
BAR=$(printf %${BAR_length}s | tr ' ' $BAR_character)

work_todo=$(get_work_todo)             # how much there is to do

while true; do
    work_done=$(get_work_done)         # how much has been done so far
    i=$(( $work_done * $BAR_length / $work_todo ))
    echo -ne "\r${BAR:0:$i}"
    if [ $work_done == $work_todo ]; then
        echo ""
        break;
    fi
    sleep .1
done
```

- `printf` - a builtin for printing stuff in a given format
- `printf %50s` - print nothing but pad it with 50 spaces
- `tr  ' '  '#'` - translate every space to hash sign

And this is how you'd use it:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/path/to/source/file"
tgt="/path/to/target/file"

function get_work_todo() {
    echo $(stat -c%s "$src")
}

function get_work_done() {
    [ -e "$tgt" ] &&                   # if target file exists
        echo $(stat -c%s "$tgt") ||    # echo its size, else
        echo 0                         # echo zero
}

cp "$src" "$tgt" &                     # copy in the background

source /usr/lib/progress_bar.sh        # execute the progress bar
```

Obviously you can wrap this in a function, rewrite to work with piped streams, grab forked process ID with `$!` and pass it to `progress_bar.sh` so it could *guess* how to calculate work to do and work done, whatever's your poison.

### Side notes

I get asked about these two things most often:

1. `${}`: in above examples I use `${foo:A:B}`. The technical term for this syntax is *Parameter Expansion*, a built-in shell functionality that allows to manipulate a variable (parameter), e.g. to trim a string with `:` but also to do other things - it does not spawn a subshell. The most prominent description of parameter expansion I can think of (that isn't fully POSIX compatible but lets the reader understand the concept well) is in the `man bash` page.
2. `$()`: in above examples I use `foo=$(bar)`. It spawns a separate shell in a subprocess (a.k.a. a *Subshell*), runs the `bar` command in it and assigns its standard output to a `$foo` variable. It's not the same as *Process Substitution* and it's something entirely different than *pipe* (`|`). Most importantly, it works. Some say this should be avoided because it's slow. I argue this is "a okay" here because whatever this code is trying to visualise lasts long enough to require a progress bar. In other words, subshells are not the bottleneck. Calling a subshell also saves me the effort of explaining why `return` isn't what most people think it is, what is an *Exit Status* and why passing values from functions in shells is not what shell functions are good at in general. To find out more about all of it I, again, highly recommend the `man bash` page.

### Troubleshooting

If your shell is actually running sh instead of bash, or really old bash, like default osx, it may choke on `echo -ne "\r${BAR:0:$i}"`. The exact error is `Bad substitution`. If this happens to you, per the comment section, you can instead use `echo -ne "\r$(expr "x$name" : "x.\{0,$num_skip\}\(.\{0,$num_keep\}\)")"` to do a more portable posix-compatible / less readable substring match.

A complete, working /bin/sh example:

```
#!/bin/sh

src=100
tgt=0

get_work_todo() {
    echo $src
}

do_work() {
    echo "$(( $1 + 1 ))"
}

BAR_length=50
BAR_character='#'
BAR=$(printf %${BAR_length}s | tr ' ' $BAR_character)
work_todo=$(get_work_todo)             # how much there is to do
work_done=0
while true; do
    work_done="$(do_work $work_done)"
    i=$(( $work_done * $BAR_length / $work_todo ))
    n=$(( $BAR_length - $i ))
    printf "\r$(expr "x$BAR" : "x.\{0,$n\}\(.\{0,$i\}\)")"
    if [ $work_done = $work_todo ]; then
        echo "\n"
        break;
    fi
    sleep .1
done
```

Comment: For those that want the simplest stuff I just made mine with cprn first answer. It's a very simple progress bar in a function that use some stupid proportionality rule to draw the bar: https://pastebin.com/9imhRLYX

Comment: It's correct if you use bash and not sh, otherwise some people can have a `Bad substitution` on `${BAR:0:$i}`.

Comment: You might be right. Nowadays `sh` in many distributions is linked to `bash` or a script that runs `bash --posix` compatibility mode and I suspect it was so on my system in 2016 when I wrote and tested this answer. If it doesn't work for you you can replace `${name:n:l}` with `$(expr "x$name" : "x.\{0,$n\}\(.\{0,$l\}\)")` which is proven to work in any POSIX shell (originated in `ksh93` and is also present in `zsh`, `mksh` and `busyboxsh`). I'm leaving the original answer, though, for readability and because it should just work in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 31):

## Hires (floating point) progress bar

#### *Preamble*

Sorry for this *not so short* answer. In this answer I will use ***`integer`*** to render floating point, ***`UTF-8`*** fonts for rendering progress bar more finely, and ***`parallelise`*** another task (*`sha1sum`*) in order to follow his progression, all of this with minimal resource footprint using ***pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)*** and ***no forks***.

> **For impatiens:** Please test code (copy/paste in a new terminal window) at ***Now do it!*** (in the middle), with
>
> - either: ***Last animated demo*** (near end of this.),
> - either ***Practical sample*** (at end).

All demos here use `read -t <float seconds> && break` instead of `sleep`. So all loop could be nicely stopped by hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

### Introduction

***Yet Another Bash Progress Bar...***

As there is already a lot of answer here, I want to add some hints about ***performances*** and ***precision***.

### 1. Avoid forks!

Because a progress bar are intented to run while other process are working, this must be a ***nice*** process...

So avoid using ***forks*** when not needed. Sample: instead of

```bash
mysmiley=$(printf '%b' \\U1F60E)
```

Use

```bash
printf -v mysmiley '%b' \\U1F60E
```

**Explanation:** When you run `var=$(command)`, you initiate a new process to execute `command` and send his *output* to variable *`$var`* once terminated. This is **very** resource expensive. Please compare:

```bash
TIMEFORMAT="%R"
time for ((i=2500;i--;)){ mysmiley=$(printf '%b' \\U1F60E);}
2.292
time for ((i=2500;i--;)){ printf -v mysmiley '%b' \\U1F60E;}
0.017
bc -l <<<'2.292/.017'
134.82352941176470588235
```

On my host, same work of assigning `$mysmiley` (just 2500 time), seem ~135x slower / more expensive by using *fork* than by using built-in `printf -v`.

Then

```bash
echo $mysmiley
```

So your *`function`* have to not print (or *output*) anything. Your function have to attribute his answer to a ***variable***.

### 2. Use integer as pseudo floating point

Here is a very small and quick function to compute percents from integers, with integer and answer a pseudo floating point number:

```bash
percent(){
    local p=00$(($1*100000/$2))
    printf -v "$3" %.2f ${p::-3}.${p: -3}
}
```

Usage:

```bash
# percent <integer to compare> <reference integer> <variable name>
percent 33333 50000 testvar
printf '%8s%%\n' "$testvar"
   66.67%
```

### 3. Hires console graphic using UTF-8: *`▏ ▎ ▍ ▌ ▋ ▊ ▉ █`*

To render this characters using bash, you could:

```bash
printf -v chars '\\U258%X ' {15..8}
printf '%b\n' "$chars"
▏ ▎ ▍ ▌ ▋ ▊ ▉ █
```

or

```bash
printf %b\  \\U258{{f..a},9,8}
▏ ▎ ▍ ▌ ▋ ▊ ▉ █
```

Then we have to use 8x *`string width`* as *`graphic width`*.

## Now do it!

This function is named `percentBar` because it render a bar from argument submited in percents (floating):

```bash
percentBar ()  { 
    local prct totlen=$((8*$2)) lastchar barstring blankstring;
    printf -v prct %.2f "$1"
    ((prct=10#${prct/.}*totlen/10000, prct%8)) &&
        printf -v lastchar '\\U258%X' $(( 16 - prct%8 )) ||
            lastchar=''
    printf -v barstring '%*s' $((prct/8)) ''
    printf -v barstring '%b' "${barstring// /\\U2588}$lastchar"
    printf -v blankstring '%*s' $(((totlen-prct)/8)) ''
    printf -v "$3" '%s%s' "$barstring" "$blankstring"
}
```

Usage:

```
# percentBar <float percent> <int string width> <variable name>
percentBar 42.42 $COLUMNS bar1
echo "$bar1"
█████████████████████████████████▉
```

To show little differences:

```
percentBar 42.24 $COLUMNS bar2
printf "%s\n" "$bar1" "$bar2"
█████████████████████████████████▉                                              
█████████████████████████████████▊
```

#### With colors

As rendered variable is a fixed widht string, using color is easy:

```
percentBar 72.1 24 bar
printf 'Show this: \e[44;33;1m%s\e[0m at %s%%\n' "$bar" 72.1
```

[image: Bar with color]

#### Little animation:

```bash
for i in {0..10000..33} 10000;do i=0$i
    printf -v p %0.2f ${i::-2}.${i: -2}
    percentBar $p $((COLUMNS-9)) bar
    printf '\r|%s|%6.2f%%' "$bar" $p
    read -srt .002 _ && break    # console sleep avoiding fork
done

|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████|100.00%
```

```bash
clear; for i in {0..10000..33} 10000;do i=0$i
     printf -v p %0.2f ${i::-2}.${i: -2}
     percentBar $p $((COLUMNS-7)) bar
     printf '\r\e[47;30m%s\e[0m%6.2f%%' "$bar" $p
     read -srt .002 _ && break
done
```

[image: PercentBar animation]

## Last animated demo

Another demo showing different sizes and colored output:

```bash
printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\e[8A\e7'&&for i in {0..9999..99} 10000;do 
    o=1 i=0$i;printf -v p %0.2f ${i::-2}.${i: -2}
    for l in 1 2 3 5 8 13 20 40 $((COLUMNS-7));do
        percentBar $p $l bar$((o++));done
    [ "$p" = "100.00" ] && read -rst .8 _;printf \\e8
    printf '%s\e[48;5;23;38;5;41m%s\e[0m%6.2f%%%b' 'In 1 char width: ' \
        "$bar1" $p ,\\n 'with 2 chars: ' "$bar2" $p ,\\n 'or 3 chars: ' \
        "$bar3" $p ,\\n 'in 5 characters: ' "$bar4" $p ,\\n 'in 8 chars: ' \
        "$bar5" $p .\\n 'There are 13 chars: ' "$bar6" $p ,\\n '20 chars: '\
        "$bar7" $p ,\\n 'then 40 chars' "$bar8" $p \
        ', or full width:\n' '' "$bar9" $p ''
    ((10#$i)) || read -st .5 _; read -st .1 _ && break
done
```

Could produce something like this:

[image: Last animation percentBar animation]

### Practical *GNU/Linux* sample 1: kind of `sleep` with progress bar

**Rewrite feb 2023**: Turn into more usefull `displaySleep` function suitable to use as *displayed timeout read*:

This sleep show a progress bar with 50 refresh by seconds (tunnable)

```bash
percent(){ local p=00$(($1*100000/$2));printf -v "$3" %.2f ${p::-3}.${p: -3};}
displaySleep() {
    local -i refrBySeconds=50
    local -i _start=${EPOCHREALTIME/.} reqslp target crtslp crtp cols cpos dlen
    local strng percent prctbar tleft
    [[ $COLUMNS ]] && cols=${COLUMNS} || read -r cols < <(tput cols)
    refrBySeconds=' 1000000 / refrBySeconds '
    printf -v strng %.6f $1
    printf '\E[6n' && IFS=\; read -sdR _ cpos
    dlen=${#strng}-1  cols=' cols - dlen - cpos -1 '
    printf \\e7
    reqslp=10#${strng/.} target=reqslp+_start
    for ((;${EPOCHREALTIME/.}<target;)){
        crtp=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
        crtslp='( target - crtp ) > refrBySeconds? refrBySeconds: target - crtp'
        strng=00000$crtslp  crtp+=-_start
        printf -v strng %.6f ${strng::-6}.${strng: -6}
        percent $crtp $reqslp percent
        percentBar $percent $cols prctbar
        tleft=00000$((reqslp-crtp))
        printf '\e8\e[36;48;5;23m%s\e[0m%*.4fs' \
               "$prctbar" "$dlen" ${tleft::-6}.${tleft: -6}
        IFS= read -rsn1 -t $strng ${2:-_} && { echo; return;}
    }
    percentBar 100 $cols prctbar
    printf '\e8\e[36;48;5;30m%s\e[0m%*.4fs\n' "$prctbar" "$dlen" 0
    false
}
```

This will **keep** *current cursor position* to fill only the **rest** of line (full line if current cursor position is 1). This could be useful for displaying some kind of *prompt*:

[image]

### Practical *GNU/Linux* sample 2: `sha1sum` with progress bar

Under linux, you could find a lot of usefull infos under `/proc` pseudo filesystem, so using previoulsy defined functions `percentBar` and `percent`, here is `sha1progress`:

```bash
percent(){ local p=00$(($1*100000/$2));printf -v "$3" %.2f ${p::-3}.${p: -3};}
sha1Progress() { 
    local -i totsize crtpos cols=$(tput cols) sha1in sha1pid
    local sha1res percent prctbar
    exec {sha1in}< <(exec sha1sum -b - <"$1")
    sha1pid=$!
    read -r totsize < <(stat -Lc %s "$1")
    while ! read -ru $sha1in -t .025 sha1res _; do
        read -r _ crtpos < /proc/$sha1pid/fdinfo/0
        percent $crtpos $totsize percent
        percentBar $percent $((cols-8)) prctbar
        printf '\r\e[44;38;5;25m%s\e[0m%6.2f%%' "$prctbar" $percent;

    done
    printf "\r%s  %s\e[K\n" $sha1res "$1"
}
```

Of course, *`25 ms`* timeout mean approx 40 refresh per second. This could look overkill, but work fine on my host, and anyway, this can be tunned.

[image: sha1Progress sample]

Explanation:

- `exec {sha1in}<` create a new *file descriptor* for the output of
- `<( ... )` forked task run in background
- `sha1sum -b - <"$1"` ensuring input came from STDIN (`fd/0`)
- `while ! read -ru $sha1in -t .025 sha1res _` While no input read from subtask, in *`25 ms`*...
- `/proc/$sha1pid/fdinfo/0` kernel variable showing information about *file descriptor 0* (STDIN) of task `$sha1pid`

Comment: Beautiful answer! In the first animated demo, I see the `\r` that causes the cursor to reset so the bar re-draws itself, but in the second animated demo how are you accomplishing that?

Comment: @David 1st line print 8 lines then `Esc[8A` to return 8 lines higher. Then `Esc7` *save cursor position*... Lather, `Esc8` *restore cursor position*.

Comment: That's cool, it is so amazing

Comment: @David You could be interested by [Bash - Clearing the last output correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040654/1765658)!

Answer (score 26):

### APT style progress bar (Does not break normal output)

[image]

EDIT: For an updated version check my [github page](https://github.com/pollev/bash_progress_bar)

I was not satisfied with the responses on this question. What I was personally looking for was a fancy progress bar as is seen by APT.

I had a look at the C source code for APT and decided to write my own equivalent for bash.

**This progress bar will stay nicely at the bottom of the terminal and will not interfere with any output sent to the terminal.**

Please do note that the bar is currently fixed at 100 characters wide. If you want scale it to the size of the terminal, this is fairly easy to accomplish as well (The updated version on my github page handles this well).

I will post my script here.
Usage example:

```
source ./progress_bar.sh
echo "This is some output"
setup_scroll_area
sleep 1
echo "This is some output 2"
draw_progress_bar 10
sleep 1
echo "This is some output 3"
draw_progress_bar 50
sleep 1
echo "This is some output 4"
draw_progress_bar 90
sleep 1
echo "This is some output 5"
destroy_scroll_area
```

The script (I strongly recommend the version on my github instead):

```
#!/bin/bash

# This code was inspired by the open source C code of the APT progress bar
# http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/apt/trusty/view/head:/apt-pkg/install-progress.cc#L233

#
# Usage:
# Source this script
# setup_scroll_area
# draw_progress_bar 10
# draw_progress_bar 90
# destroy_scroll_area
#


CODE_SAVE_CURSOR="\033[s"
CODE_RESTORE_CURSOR="\033[u"
CODE_CURSOR_IN_SCROLL_AREA="\033[1A"
COLOR_FG="\e[30m"
COLOR_BG="\e[42m"
RESTORE_FG="\e[39m"
RESTORE_BG="\e[49m"

function setup_scroll_area() {
    lines=$(tput lines)
    let lines=$lines-1
    # Scroll down a bit to avoid visual glitch when the screen area shrinks by one row
    echo -en "\n"

    # Save cursor
    echo -en "$CODE_SAVE_CURSOR"
    # Set scroll region (this will place the cursor in the top left)
    echo -en "\033[0;${lines}r"

    # Restore cursor but ensure its inside the scrolling area
    echo -en "$CODE_RESTORE_CURSOR"
    echo -en "$CODE_CURSOR_IN_SCROLL_AREA"

    # Start empty progress bar
    draw_progress_bar 0
}

function destroy_scroll_area() {
    lines=$(tput lines)
    # Save cursor
    echo -en "$CODE_SAVE_CURSOR"
    # Set scroll region (this will place the cursor in the top left)
    echo -en "\033[0;${lines}r"

    # Restore cursor but ensure its inside the scrolling area
    echo -en "$CODE_RESTORE_CURSOR"
    echo -en "$CODE_CURSOR_IN_SCROLL_AREA"

    # We are done so clear the scroll bar
    clear_progress_bar

    # Scroll down a bit to avoid visual glitch when the screen area grows by one row
    echo -en "\n\n"
}

function draw_progress_bar() {
    percentage=$1
    lines=$(tput lines)
    let lines=$lines
    # Save cursor
    echo -en "$CODE_SAVE_CURSOR"

    # Move cursor position to last row
    echo -en "\033[${lines};0f"

    # Clear progress bar
    tput el

    # Draw progress bar
    print_bar_text $percentage

    # Restore cursor position
    echo -en "$CODE_RESTORE_CURSOR"
}

function clear_progress_bar() {
    lines=$(tput lines)
    let lines=$lines
    # Save cursor
    echo -en "$CODE_SAVE_CURSOR"

    # Move cursor position to last row
    echo -en "\033[${lines};0f"

    # clear progress bar
    tput el

    # Restore cursor position
    echo -en "$CODE_RESTORE_CURSOR"
}

function print_bar_text() {
    local percentage=$1

    # Prepare progress bar
    let remainder=100-$percentage
    progress_bar=$(echo -ne "["; echo -en "${COLOR_FG}${COLOR_BG}"; printf_new "#" $percentage; echo -en "${RESTORE_FG}${RESTORE_BG}"; printf_new "." $remainder; echo -ne "]");

    # Print progress bar
    if [ $1 -gt 99 ]
    then
        echo -ne "${progress_bar}"
    else
        echo -ne "${progress_bar}"
    fi
}

printf_new() {
    str=$1
    num=$2
    v=$(printf "%-${num}s" "$str")
    echo -ne "${v// /$str}"
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for

Comment: Avoid forks!! Dont write `var=$(printf...)` but `printf -v var ...`, no `var=$(echo -n ...;printf)` but `printf -v var ...; var=...${var}...`

Comment: THIS! This is the goods I was looking for.

I don't want to learn how to use "\r" to repaint a line, I want to see how to draw over a chunk of the screen! Bravo!

Answer (score 19):

[GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/checkpoints.html#SEC47) has a useful option which gives a functionality of a simple progress bar.

(...) Another available checkpoint action is ‘dot’ (or ‘.’). It instructs tar to print a single dot on the standard listing stream, e.g.:

```
$ tar -c --checkpoint=1000 --checkpoint-action=dot /var
...
```

The same effect may be obtained by:

```
$ tar -c --checkpoint=.1000 /var
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest approach!  If you see no dots printed, try to decrease the number, for example `--checkpoint=.10`. It also works great when extracting with `tar -xz`.

Answer (score 14):

A simpler method that works on my system using the pipeview ( pv ) utility.

```
srcdir=$1
outfile=$2


tar -Ocf - $srcdir | pv -i 1 -w 50 -berps `du -bs $srcdir | awk '{print $1}'` | 7za a -si $outfile
```

Answer (score 13):

### Here is how it might look

*Uploading a file*

```
[##################################################] 100% (137921 / 137921 bytes)
```

*Waiting for a job to complete*

```
[#########################                         ] 50% (15 / 30 seconds)
```

### Simple function that implements it

You can just copy-paste it to your script. It does not require anything else to work.

```
PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH=50  # progress bar length in characters

draw_progress_bar() {
  # Arguments: current value, max value, unit of measurement (optional)
  local __value=$1
  local __max=$2
  local __unit=${3:-""}  # if unit is not supplied, do not display it

  # Calculate percentage
  if (( $__max < 1 )); then __max=1; fi  # anti zero division protection
  local __percentage=$(( 100 - ($__max*100 - $__value*100) / $__max ))

  # Rescale the bar according to the progress bar width
  local __num_bar=$(( $__percentage * $PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH / 100 ))

  # Draw progress bar
  printf "["
  for b in $(seq 1 $__num_bar); do printf "#"; done
  for s in $(seq 1 $(( $PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH - $__num_bar ))); do printf " "; done
  printf "] $__percentage%% ($__value / $__max $__unit)\r"
}
```

### Usage example

Here, we upload a file and redraw the progress bar at each iteration. It does not matter what job is actually performed as long as we can get 2 values: max value and current value.

In the example below the max value is `file_size` and the current value is supplied by some function and is called `uploaded_bytes`.

```
# Uploading a file
file_size=137921

while true; do
  # Get current value of uploaded bytes
  uploaded_bytes=$(some_function_that_reports_progress)

  # Draw a progress bar
  draw_progress_bar $uploaded_bytes $file_size "bytes"

  # Check if we reached 100%
  if [ $uploaded_bytes == $file_size ]; then break; fi
  sleep 1  # Wait before redrawing
done
# Go to the newline at the end of upload
printf "\n"
```

Comment: Neat and simple function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is what I am searching for! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 11):

This lets you visualize that a command is still executing:

```
while :;do echo -n .;sleep 1;done &
trap "kill $!" EXIT  #Die with parent if we die prematurely
tar zxf packages.tar.gz; # or any other command here
kill $! && trap " " EXIT #Kill the loop and unset the trap or else the pid might get reassigned and we might end up killing a completely different process
```

This will create an **infinite while loop** that executes in the background and echoes a "." every second. This will display `.` in the shell. Run the `tar` command or any a command you want. When that command finishes executing then **kill** the last job running in the background - which is the **infinite while loop**.

Comment: Couldn't another job start in the background during execution and potentially get killed instead of the progress loop?

Comment: I think the idea is you would put this in a script, so this would only trap an exit of that script.

Comment: I love this command, I'm using it in my files. I'm just a little uneasy since I don't really understand how it works. The first and third lines are easier to understand, but I'm still not sure. I know this is an old answer, but is there a way I can get a different explanation geared towards newbies at programing

Comment: This is the ONLY true answer, where others are just Scripting 101 toy progress bars that mean nothing and are no use for real, one-off, untrackable (almost ALL) programs. Thank you.

Comment: @Felipe, The while loop is a background process. The $! in the first trap captures the process id of that background process and ensures that if the current/parent process ends the background process dies too and it's not left hanging. The kill statement just ends the background process when your long command or commands end.

Comment: I like this idea but it doesn't represent the progress, it only proves the parent process exists. The amount of `.` displayed has nothing to do with the amount of job done and there's no such thing as a "full bar" here.

Comment: When using this after my command (in my case `find`) in the console is finished it prints out e.g. `./fetchAllRepos: line 25: 35150 Terminated      while true; do for x in '-' '/' '|' '\'; do echo -ne "\b"$x; sleep 0.1; done; done` Is there a way to avoid this getting printed?

Comment: @Centimane you could store the PID in a variable (i,e. `pid=$!`) right after backgrounding the while loop and use the variable later even in trap declaration:

Comment: @cprn If you like this approach, maybe would you appreciate my [sha1progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298090/1765658) Note I don't use `trap` or `kill`, but 1 fork efficiently watched for one line output!

Answer (score 6):

I needed a progress bar for iterating over the lines in a csv file. Was able to adapt cprn's code into something useful for me:

```
BAR='##############################'
FILL='------------------------------'
totalLines=$(wc -l $file | awk '{print $1}')  # num. lines in file
barLen=30

# --- iterate over lines in csv file ---
count=0
while IFS=, read -r _ col1 col2 col3; do
    # update progress bar
    count=$(($count + 1))
    percent=$((($count * 100 / $totalLines * 100) / 100))
    i=$(($percent * $barLen / 100))
    echo -ne "\r[${BAR:0:$i}${FILL:$i:barLen}] $count/$totalLines ($percent%)"

    # other stuff
    (...)
done <$file
```

Looks like this:

```
[##----------------------------] 17128/218210 (7%)
```

Comment: Thx for the solution! Worked as I need.

Answer (score 5):

Most unix commands will not give you the sort of direct feedback from which you can do this.
Some will give you output on stdout or stderr that you can use.

For something like tar you could use the -v switch and pipe the output to a program that updates a small animation for each line it reads.  As tar writes out a list of files it's unravelled the program can update the animation.  To do a percent complete you would have to know the number of files and count the lines.

cp doesn't give this sort of output as far as I know.  To monitor the progress of cp you would have to monitor the source and destination files and watch the size of the destination.  You could write a small c program using the [stat (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call to get the file size.  This would read the size of the source then poll the destination file and update a % complete bar based on the size of the file written to date.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the work of Edouard Lopez, I created a progress bar that fits the size of the screen, whatever it is. Check it out.

[image]

It's also posted on [Git Hub](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/progressbar.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Progress bar by Adriano Pinaffo
# Available at https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/progressbar.sh
# Inspired on work by Edouard Lopez (https://github.com/edouard-lopez/progress-bar.sh)
# Version 1.0
# Date April, 28th 2017

function error {
  echo "Usage: $0 [SECONDS]"
  case $1 in
    1) echo "Pass one argument only"
    exit 1
    ;;
    2) echo "Parameter must be a number"
    exit 2
    ;;
    *) echo "Unknown error"
    exit 999
  esac
}

[[ $# -ne 1 ]] && error 1
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || error 2

duration=${1}
barsize=$((`tput cols` - 7))
unity=$(($barsize / $duration))
increment=$(($barsize%$duration))
skip=$(($duration/($duration-$increment)))
curr_bar=0
prev_bar=
for (( elapsed=1; elapsed<=$duration; elapsed++ ))
do
  # Elapsed
prev_bar=$curr_bar
  let curr_bar+=$unity
  [[ $increment -eq 0 ]] || {  
    [[ $skip -eq 1 ]] &&
      { [[ $(($elapsed%($duration/$increment))) -eq 0 ]] && let curr_bar++; } ||
    { [[ $(($elapsed%$skip)) -ne 0 ]] && let curr_bar++; }
  }
  [[ $elapsed -eq 1 && $increment -eq 1 && $skip -ne 1 ]] && let curr_bar++
  [[ $(($barsize-$curr_bar)) -eq 1 ]] && let curr_bar++
  [[ $curr_bar -lt $barsize ]] || curr_bar=$barsize
  for (( filled=0; filled<=$curr_bar; filled++ )); do
    printf "▇"
  done

  # Remaining
  for (( remain=$curr_bar; remain<$barsize; remain++ )); do
    printf " "
  done

  # Percentage
  printf "| %s%%" $(( ($elapsed*100)/$duration))

  # Return
  sleep 1
  printf "\r"
done
printf "\n"
exit 0
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

I needed a progress bar that would fit in popup bubble message (`notify-send`) to represent TV volume level. Recently I've been writing a music player in python and the TV picture is turned off most of the time.

### Sample output from terminal

[image: test_progress_bar3.gif]

---

### Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Show a progress bar at step number $1 (from 0 to 100)


function is_int() { test "$@" -eq "$@" 2> /dev/null; } 

# Parameter 1 must be integer
if ! is_int "$1" ; then
   echo "Not an integer: ${1}"
   exit 1
fi

# Parameter 1 must be >= 0 and <= 100
if [ "$1" -ge 0 ] && [ "$1" -le 100 ]  2>/dev/null
then
    :
else
    echo bad volume: ${1}
    exit 1
fi

# Main function designed for quickly copying to another program 
Main () {

    Bar=""                      # Progress Bar / Volume level
    Len=25                      # Length of Progress Bar / Volume level
    Div=4                       # Divisor into Volume for # of blocks
    Fill="▒"                    # Fill up to $Len
    Arr=( "▉" "▎" "▌" "▊" )     # UTF-8 left blocks: 7/8, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4

    FullBlock=$((${1} / Div))   # Number of full blocks
    PartBlock=$((${1} % Div))   # Size of partial block (array index)

    while [[ $FullBlock -gt 0 ]]; do
        Bar="$Bar${Arr[0]}"     # Add 1 full block into Progress Bar
        (( FullBlock-- ))       # Decrement full blocks counter
    done

    # If remainder zero no partial block, else append character from array
    if [[ $PartBlock -gt 0 ]]; then
        Bar="$Bar${Arr[$PartBlock]}"
    fi

    while [[ "${#Bar}" -lt "$Len" ]]; do
        Bar="$Bar$Fill"         # Pad Progress Bar with fill character
    done

    echo Volume: "$1 $Bar"
    exit 0                      # Remove this line when copying into program
} # Main

Main "$@"
```

---

### Test bash script

Use this script to test the progress bar in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

# test_progress_bar3

Main () {

    tput civis                              # Turn off cursor
    for ((i=0; i<=100; i++)); do
        CurrLevel=$(./progress_bar3 "$i")   # Generate progress bar 0 to 100
        echo -ne "$CurrLevel"\\r            # Reprint overtop same line
        sleep .04
    done
    echo -e \\n                             # Advance line to keep last progress
    echo "$0 Done"
    tput cnorm                              # Turn cursor back on
} # Main

Main "$@"
```

---

## TL;DR

This section details how `notify-send` is used to quickly spam popup bubble messages to the desktop. This is required because volume level can change many times a second and the default bubble message behavior is for a message to stay on the desktop for many seconds.

### Sample popup bubble message

[image: tvpowered.gif]

### Popup bubble message bash code

From the script above the `main` function was copied to a new functioned called `VolumeBar` in an existing bash script called `tvpowered`. The `exit 0` command in the copied `main` function was removed.

Here's how to call it and let Ubuntu's `notify-send` command know we will be spamming popup bubble message:

```
VolumeBar $CurrVolume
# Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/871207/307523
notify-send --urgency=critical "tvpowered" \
    -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:volume \
    --icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/devices/audio-speakers.png \
    "Volume: $CurrVolume $Bar"
```

This is the new line which tells `notify-send` to immediately replace last popup bubble:

```
-h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:volume \
```

`volume` groups the popup bubble messages together and new messages in this group immediately replaces the previous. You can use `anything` instead of `volume`.

Answer (score 4):

My solution displays the percentage of the tarball that
is currently being uncompressed and written. I use this
when writing out 2GB root filesystem images. You really
need a progress bar for these things. What I do is use
`gzip --list` to get the total uncompressed size of the
tarball. From that I calculate the blocking-factor needed
to divide the file into 100 parts. Finally, I print a
checkpoint message for each block. For a 2GB file this
gives about 10MB a block. If that is too big then you can
divide the BLOCKING_FACTOR by 10 or 100, but then it's
harder to print pretty output in terms of a percentage.

Assuming you are using Bash then you can use the
following shell function

```
untar_progress () 
{ 
  TARBALL=$1
  BLOCKING_FACTOR=$(gzip --list ${TARBALL} |
    perl -MPOSIX -ane '$.==2 && print ceil $F[1]/50688')
  tar --blocking-factor=${BLOCKING_FACTOR} --checkpoint=1 \
    --checkpoint-action='ttyout=Wrote %u%  \r' -zxf ${TARBALL}
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but how do you do when you want to compress a directory ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all bar is not the only one pipe progress meter. The other (maybe even more known) is pv (pipe viewer).

Secondly bar and pv can be used for example like this:

```
$ bar file1 | wc -l 
$ pv file1 | wc -l
```

or even:

```
$ tail -n 100 file1 | bar | wc -l
$ tail -n 100 file1 | pv | wc -l
```

one useful trick if you want to make use of bar and pv in commands that are working with files given in arguments, like e.g. copy file1 file2, is to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
$ copy <(bar file1) file2
$ copy <(pv file1) file2
```

Process substitution is a bash magic thing that creates temporary fifo pipe files /dev/fd/ and connect stdout from runned process (inside parenthesis) through this pipe and copy sees it just like an ordinary file (with one exception, it can only read it forwards).

Update:

bar command itself allows also for copying. After man bar:

```
bar --in-file /dev/rmt/1cbn --out-file \
     tape-restore.tar --size 2.4g --buffer-size 64k
```

But process substitution is in my opinion more generic way to do it. An it uses cp program itself.

Answer (score 4):

Many answers describe writing your own commands for printing out `'\r' + $some_sort_of_progress_msg`. The problem sometimes is that printing out hundreds of these updates per second will slow down the process.

However, if any of your processes produce output (eg `7z a -r newZipFile myFolder` will output each filename as it compresses it) then a simpler, fast, painless and customisable solution exists.

Install the python module `tqdm`.

```
$ sudo pip install tqdm
$ # now have fun
$ 7z a -r -bd newZipFile myFolder | tqdm >> /dev/null
$ # if we know the expected total, we can have a bar!
$ 7z a -r -bd newZipFile myFolder | grep -o Compressing | tqdm --total $(find myFolder -type f | wc -l) >> /dev/null
```

Help: `tqdm -h`. An example using more options:

```
$ find / -name '*.py' -exec cat \{} \; | tqdm --unit loc --unit_scale True | wc -l
```

As a bonus you can also use `tqdm` to wrap iterables in python code.

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/README.rst#module

Comment: I don't think your example with "more options" works. It seems to pass the `tqdm` STDOUT to `wc -l` through a pipe. You probably want to escape that.

Comment: @cprn `tqdm` will show progress on `STDERR` while piping its input `STDIN` to `STDOUT`. In this case `wc -l` whould receive the same input as if `tqdm` was not included.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use *dialog* with the *--gauge* param. Is used very often in .deb package installations and other basic configuration stuff of many distros. So you don't need to reinvent the wheel... again

Just put an int value from 1 to 100 @stdin. One basic and silly example:

```
for a in {1..100}; do sleep .1s; echo $a| dialog --gauge "waiting" 7 30; done
```

I have this */bin/Wait* file (with chmod u+x perms) for cooking purposes :P

```
#!/bin/bash
INIT=`/bin/date +%s`
NOW=$INIT
FUTURE=`/bin/date -d "$1" +%s`
[ $FUTURE -a $FUTURE -eq $FUTURE ] || exit
DIFF=`echo "$FUTURE - $INIT"|bc -l`

while [ $INIT -le $FUTURE -a $NOW -lt $FUTURE ]; do
    NOW=`/bin/date +%s`
    STEP=`echo "$NOW - $INIT"|bc -l`
    SLEFT=`echo "$FUTURE - $NOW"|bc -l`
    MLEFT=`echo "scale=2;$SLEFT/60"|bc -l`
    TEXT="$SLEFT seconds left ($MLEFT minutes)";
    TITLE="Waiting $1: $2"
    sleep 1s
    PTG=`echo "scale=0;$STEP * 100 / $DIFF"|bc -l`
    echo $PTG| dialog --title "$TITLE" --gauge "$TEXT" 7 72
done

if [ "$2" == "" ]; then msg="Espera terminada: $1";audio="Listo";
else msg=$2;audio=$2;fi 

/usr/bin/notify-send --icon=stock_appointment-reminder-excl "$msg"
espeak -v spanish "$audio"
```

So I can put:

`Wait "34 min" "warm up the oven"`

or

`Wait "dec 31" "happy new year"`

Answer (score 2):

This is only applicable using gnome zenity.  Zenity provides a great native interface to bash scripts:
**https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/**

From Zenity Progress Bar  Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo "10" ; sleep 1
echo "# Updating mail logs" ; sleep 1
echo "20" ; sleep 1
echo "# Resetting cron jobs" ; sleep 1
echo "50" ; sleep 1
echo "This line will just be ignored" ; sleep 1
echo "75" ; sleep 1
echo "# Rebooting system" ; sleep 1
echo "100" ; sleep 1
) |
zenity --progress \
  --title="Update System Logs" \
  --text="Scanning mail logs..." \
  --percentage=0

if [ "$?" = -1 ] ; then
        zenity --error \
          --text="Update canceled."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

To indicate progress of activity, try the following commands:

```
while true; do sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r\\" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r|" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r/" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r-"; done;
```

**OR**

```
while true; do sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\rActivity: \\" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\rActivity: |" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\rActivity: /" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\rActivity: -"; done;
```

**OR**

```
while true; do sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r>" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r>>" && sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r>>>"; sleep 0.25 && echo -ne "\r>>>>"; done;
```

**OR**

```
while true; do sleep .25 && echo -ne "\r:Active:" && sleep .25 && echo -ne "\r:aCtive:" && sleep .25 && echo -ne "\r:acTive:" && sleep .25 && echo -ne "\r:actIve:" && sleep .25 && echo -ne "\r:actiVe:" && sleep .25 && echo -ne "\r:activE:"; done;
```

One can use **flags/variables** inside the while loop to check and display the value/extent of progress.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/extensionsapp/progre.sh

Create 40 percent progress: `progreSh 40`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It may be achieved in a pretty simple way:

- iterate from 0 to 100 with `for` loop
- sleep every step for 25ms (0.25 second)
- append to the `$bar` variable another `=` sign to make the progress bar wider
- echo progress bar and percentage (`\r` cleans line and returns to the beginning of the line; `-ne` makes `echo` doesn't add newline at the end and parses `\r` special character)

```
function progress {
    bar=''
    for (( x=0; x <= 100; x++ )); do
        sleep 0.25
        bar="${bar}="
        echo -ne "$bar ${x}%\r"
    done
    echo -e "\n"
}
```

```
$ progress
> ========== 10% # here: after 2.5 seconds
```

```
$ progress
> ============================== 30% # here: after 7.5 seconds
```

**COLORED PROGRESS BAR**

```
function progress {
    bar=''
    for (( x=0; x <= 100; x++ )); do
        sleep 0.05
        bar="${bar} "

        echo -ne "\r"
        echo -ne "\e[43m$bar\e[0m"

        local left="$(( 100 - $x ))"
        printf " %${left}s"
        echo -n "${x}%"
    done
    echo -e "\n"
}
```

To make a progress bar colorful, you can use formatting escape sequence - here the progress bar is yellow: `\e[43m`, then we reset custom settings with `\e[0m`, otherwise it would affect further input even when the progress bar is done.

[image: custom progress bar]

Answer (score 1):

for me easiest to use and best looking so far is command `pv` or `bar` like some guy already wrote

for example: need to make a backup of entire drive with `dd`

normally you use `dd if="$input_drive_path" of="$output_file_path"`

with `pv` you can make it like this :

`dd if="$input_drive_path" | pv | dd of="$output_file_path"`

and the progress goes directly to `STDOUT` as this:

```
    7.46GB 0:33:40 [3.78MB/s] [  <=>                                            ]
```

after it is done summary comes up

```
    15654912+0 records in
    15654912+0 records out
    8015314944 bytes (8.0 GB) copied, 2020.49 s, 4.0 MB/s
```

Comment: Can you use `pv` or `bar` to visualize progress of different processes, e.g. timer countdown, position in a text file, your app installation, runtime set up, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I used an answer from [Creating string of repeated characters in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211891/creating-string-of-repeated-characters-in-shell-script) for char repeating. I have two relatively small **bash** versions for scripts that need to display progress bar (for example, a loop that goes through many files, but not useful for big tar files or copy operations). The faster one consists of two functions, one to prepare the strings for bar display:

```
preparebar() {
# $1 - bar length
# $2 - bar char
    barlen=$1
    barspaces=$(printf "%*s" "$1")
    barchars=$(printf "%*s" "$1" | tr ' ' "$2")
}
```

and one to display a progress bar:

```
progressbar() {
# $1 - number (-1 for clearing the bar)
# $2 - max number
    if [ $1 -eq -1 ]; then
        printf "\r  $barspaces\r"
    else
        barch=$(($1*barlen/$2))
        barsp=$((barlen-barch))
        printf "\r[%.${barch}s%.${barsp}s]\r" "$barchars" "$barspaces"
    fi
}
```

It could be used as:

```
preparebar 50 "#"
```

which means prepare strings for bar with 50 "#" characters, and after that:

```
progressbar 35 80
```

will display the number of "#" characters that corresponds to 35/80 ratio:

```
[#####################                             ]
```

Be aware that function displays the bar on the same line over and over until you (or some other program) prints a newline. If you put -1 as first parameter, the bar would be erased:

```
progressbar -1 80
```

The slower version is all in one function:

```
progressbar() {
# $1 - number
# $2 - max number
# $3 - number of '#' characters
    if [ $1 -eq -1 ]; then
        printf "\r  %*s\r" "$3"
    else
        i=$(($1*$3/$2))
        j=$(($3-i))
        printf "\r[%*s" "$i" | tr ' ' '#'
        printf "%*s]\r" "$j"
    fi
}
```

and it can be used as (the same example as above):

```
progressbar 35 80 50
```

If you need progressbar on stderr, just add `>&2` at the end of each printf command.

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestions listed above, I decided to implement my own progress bar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
  for (( i = 0; i <= 100; i=$i + 1)); do
    progress_bar "$i"
    sleep 0.1;
  done
  progress_bar "done"
  exit 0
}

progress_bar() {
  if [ "$1" == "done" ]; then
    spinner="X"
    percent_done="100"
    progress_message="Done!"
    new_line="\n"
  else
    spinner='/-\|'
    percent_done="${1:-0}"
    progress_message="$percent_done %"
  fi

  percent_none="$(( 100 - $percent_done ))"
  [ "$percent_done" -gt 0 ] && local done_bar="$(printf '#%.0s' $(seq -s ' ' 1 $percent_done))"
  [ "$percent_none" -gt 0 ] && local none_bar="$(printf '~%.0s' $(seq -s ' ' 1 $percent_none))"

  # print the progress bar to the screen
  printf "\r Progress: [%s%s] %s %s${new_line}" \
    "$done_bar" \
    "$none_bar" \
    "${spinner:x++%${#spinner}:1}" \
    "$progress_message"
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: Nice! to get it working I had to change the line `percent_none="$(( 100 - "$percent_done" ))"` to `percent_none="$(( 100 - $percent_done))"`

Answer (score 1):

Flexible version with randomized colors, a string to manipulate and date.

```sh
function spinner() {
  local PID="$1"
  local str="${2:-Processing!}"
  local delay="0.1"
  # tput civis  # hide cursor
  while ( kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null )
    do
      printf "\e[38;5;$((RANDOM%257))m%s\r\e[0m" "[$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')][      $str      ]"; sleep "$delay"
      printf "\e[38;5;$((RANDOM%257))m%s\r\e[0m" "[$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')][      $str      ]"; sleep "$delay"
      printf "\e[38;5;$((RANDOM%257))m%s\r\e[0m" "[$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')][      $str      ]"; sleep "$delay"
  done
  printf "\e[38;5;$((RANDOM%257))m%s\r\e[0m" "[$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')][ ✅  ✅  ✅   Done!   ✅  ✅  ✅ ]"; sleep "$delay"
  # tput cnorm  # restore cursor

  return 0
}
```

Usage:

```sh
# your long running proccess pushed to the background
sleep 20 &

# spinner capture-previous-proccess-id string
spinner $! 'Working!'
```

output example:

```sh
[04/06/2020 03:22:24][      Seeding!      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a pure shell version for an embedded system taking advantage of:

- /usr/bin/dd's SIGUSR1 signal handling feature.

  Basically, if you send a 'kill SIGUSR1 $(pid_of_running_dd_process)', it'll output
  a summary of throughput speed and amount transferred.
- backgrounding dd and then querying it regularly for updates, and generating
  hash ticks like old-school ftp clients used to.
- Using /dev/stdout as the destination for non-stdout friendly programs like scp

The end result allows you to take any file transfer operation and get progress update that looks like old-school FTP 'hash' output where you'd just get a hash mark for every X bytes.

This is hardly production quality code, but you get the idea. I think it's cute.

For what it's worth, the actual byte-count might not be reflected correctly in the number of hashes - you may have one more or less depending on rounding issues. Don't use this as part of a test script, it's just eye-candy. And, yes, I'm aware this is terribly inefficient - it's a shell script and I make no apologies for it.

Examples with wget, scp and tftp provided at the end. It should work with anything that has emits data. Make sure to use /dev/stdout for programs that aren't stdout friendly.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright (C) Nathan Ramella (nar+progress-script@remix.net) 2010 
# LGPLv2 license
# If you use this, send me an email to say thanks and let me know what your product
# is so I can tell all my friends I'm a big man on the internet!

progress_filter() {

        local START=$(date +"%s")
        local SIZE=1
        local DURATION=1
        local BLKSZ=51200
        local TMPFILE=/tmp/tmpfile
        local PROGRESS=/tmp/tftp.progress
        local BYTES_LAST_CYCLE=0
        local BYTES_THIS_CYCLE=0

        rm -f ${PROGRESS}

        dd bs=$BLKSZ of=${TMPFILE} 2>&1 \
                | grep --line-buffered -E '[[:digit:]]* bytes' \
                | awk '{ print $1 }' >> ${PROGRESS} &

        # Loop while the 'dd' exists. It would be 'more better' if we
        # actually looked for the specific child ID of the running 
        # process by identifying which child process it was. If someone
        # else is running dd, it will mess things up.

        # My PID handling is dumb, it assumes you only have one running dd on
        # the system, this should be fixed to just get the PID of the child
        # process from the shell.

        while [ $(pidof dd) -gt 1 ]; do

                # PROTIP: You can sleep partial seconds (at least on linux)
                sleep .5    

                # Force dd to update us on it's progress (which gets
                # redirected to $PROGRESS file.
                # 
                # dumb pid handling again
                pkill -USR1 dd

                local BYTES_THIS_CYCLE=$(tail -1 $PROGRESS)
                local XFER_BLKS=$(((BYTES_THIS_CYCLE-BYTES_LAST_CYCLE)/BLKSZ))

                # Don't print anything unless we've got 1 block or more.
                # This allows for stdin/stderr interactions to occur
                # without printing a hash erroneously.

                # Also makes it possible for you to background 'scp',
                # but still use the /dev/stdout trick _even_ if scp
                # (inevitably) asks for a password. 
                #
                # Fancy!

                if [ $XFER_BLKS -gt 0 ]; then
                        printf "#%0.s" $(seq 0 $XFER_BLKS)
                        BYTES_LAST_CYCLE=$BYTES_THIS_CYCLE
                fi
        done

        local SIZE=$(stat -c"%s" $TMPFILE)
        local NOW=$(date +"%s")

        if [ $NOW -eq 0 ]; then
                NOW=1
        fi

        local DURATION=$(($NOW-$START))
        local BYTES_PER_SECOND=$(( SIZE / DURATION ))
        local KBPS=$((SIZE/DURATION/1024))
        local MD5=$(md5sum $TMPFILE | awk '{ print $1 }')

        # This function prints out ugly stuff suitable for eval() 
        # rather than a pretty string. This makes it a bit more 
        # flexible if you have a custom format (or dare I say, locale?)

        printf "\nDURATION=%d\nBYTES=%d\nKBPS=%f\nMD5=%s\n" \
            $DURATION \
            $SIZE \
            $KBPS \
            $MD5
}
```

Examples:

```
echo "wget"
wget -q -O /dev/stdout http://www.blah.com/somefile.zip | progress_filter

echo "tftp"
tftp -l /dev/stdout -g -r something/firmware.bin 192.168.1.1 | progress_filter

echo "scp"
scp user@192.168.1.1:~/myfile.tar /dev/stdout | progress_filter
```

Comment: Decent idea, as long as you have the file size ahead of time you can provide added value than pv this way, but blindly signaling the `pidof dd` is scary.

Comment: Attempted to call that out with '# My PID handling is dumb'

Comment: You can perhaps capture `$!` from `dd` and wait on `[[ -e /proc/${DD_PID} ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to show a temporal progress bar (by knowing in advance the showing time), you can use Python as follows:

```
#!/bin/python
from time import sleep
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "<total_time>", "<progressbar_size>"
    exit()

TOTTIME=float(sys.argv[1])
BARSIZE=float(sys.argv[2])

PERCRATE=100.0/TOTTIME
BARRATE=BARSIZE/TOTTIME

for i in range(int(TOTTIME)+1):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    s = "[%-"+str(int(BARSIZE))+"s] %d%% "
    sys.stdout.write(s % ('='*int(BARRATE*i), int(PERCRATE*i)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    SLEEPTIME = 1.0
    if i == int(TOTTIME): SLEEPTIME = 0.1
    sleep(SLEEPTIME)
print ""
```

Then, assuming you saved the Python script as `progressbar.py`, it's possible to show the progress bar from your bash script by running the following command:

```
python progressbar.py 10 50
```

It would show a progress bar sized `50` characters and "running" for `10` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have built on the answer provided by fearside

This connects to an Oracle database to retrieve the progress of an RMAN restore.

```
#!/bin/bash

 # 1. Create ProgressBar function
 # 1.1 Input is currentState($1) and totalState($2)
 function ProgressBar {
 # Process data
let _progress=(${1}*100/${2}*100)/100
let _done=(${_progress}*4)/10
let _left=40-$_done
# Build progressbar string lengths
_fill=$(printf "%${_done}s")
_empty=$(printf "%${_left}s")

# 1.2 Build progressbar strings and print the ProgressBar line
# 1.2.1 Output example:
# 1.2.1.1 Progress : [########################################] 100%
printf "\rProgress : [${_fill// /#}${_empty// /-}] ${_progress}%%"

}

function rman_check {
sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
select
round((sofar/totalwork) * 100,0) pct_done
from
v\$session_longops
where
totalwork > sofar
AND
opname NOT LIKE '%aggregate%'
AND
opname like 'RMAN%';
exit
EOF
}

# Variables
_start=1

# This accounts as the "totalState" variable for the ProgressBar function
_end=100

_rman_progress=$(rman_check)
#echo ${_rman_progress}

# Proof of concept
#for number in $(seq ${_start} ${_end})

while [ ${_rman_progress} -lt 100 ]
do

for number in _rman_progress
do
sleep 10
ProgressBar ${number} ${_end}
done

_rman_progress=$(rman_check)

done
printf '\nFinished!\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function progress_bar() {
    bar=""
    total=10
    [[ -z $1 ]] && input=0 || input=${1}
    x="##"
   for i in `seq 1 10`; do
        if [ $i -le $input ] ;then
            bar=$bar$x
        else
            bar="$bar  "
       fi
    done
    #pct=$((200*$input/$total % 2 + 100*$input/$total))
    pct=$(($input*10))
    echo -ne "Progress : [ ${bar} ] (${pct}%) \r"    
    sleep 1
    if [ $input -eq 10 ] ;then
        echo -ne '\n'
    fi

}
```

could create a function that draws this on a scale say 1-10 for the number of bars :

```
progress_bar 1
echo "doing something ..."
progress_bar 2
echo "doing something ..."
progress_bar 3
echo "doing something ..."
progress_bar 8
echo "doing something ..."
progress_bar 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
tot=$(wc -c /proc/$$/fd/255 | awk '/ /{print $1}')
now() {
echo $(( 100* ($(awk '/^pos:/{print $2}' < /proc/$$/fdinfo/255)-166) / (tot-166) )) "%"
}
now;
now;
now;
now;
now;
now;
now;
now;
now;
```

output:

```
0 %
12 %
25 %
37 %
50 %
62 %
75 %
87 %
100 %
```

note: if instead of 255 you put 1 you will monitor the standard in...with 2 the standard out (but you must modify the source to set "tot" to the projected output file size)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different answers about this topic, but when calculating percentage for text file operation, using `current length / total size` way, for example showing percentage of `ver_big_file.json` progress, and I recommend using `awk` for this purpose, like below code:

```sh
awk '
    function bar(x){s="";i=0;while (i++ < x) s=s "#";return s}
    BEGIN{
        ("ls -l " ARGV[1]) | getline total;
        split(total,array);
        total=array[5];
    }
    {
        cur+=length($0)+1;
        percent=int(cur / total * 100);
        printf "LINE %s:%s %s%%\r", NR, bar(percent*.8), percent 
    }
    END {print}' very_big_file.json | grep "keyword" | ...
```

This way it's very precise, stream based, but it's only suitable for text files.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE COUNTER FOR NOT SO FANCY JOBS

I don't need really a progress bar, just a visual feedback of progress, so I prefer a simple counter after enabling the command monitored to output lines processed:

```
#!/bin/bash
# pvlines: simple script to count stdin lines read
# copy/chmod a+rx to /usr/local/bin and use: command | pvlines
awk '{N++; printf "\r%d", N} END {print ""}'
```

Create the script as indicated in the comments, then use like this:

```
tar zcvf backup.tgz dir-to-backup | pvlines
```

To process a large amount of files, first count them and then do the process, so we'll have a rough estimate of termination:

```
find /dir-to-copy | pvlines
rsync -avr /dir-to-copy user@bkserver:destination/ | pvlines
```

I found this counter have a reduced impact on the process, but it can be modified to skip some lines and report, say, each 200 or 2000 lines read.

First I did that in pure Bash with a while/read/printf loop, but it was too slow, so I migrated `pvlines` to `awk`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a psychedelic progressbar for bash scripting by nExace. It can be called from command line as './progressbar x y' where 'x' is a time in seconds and 'y' is a message associated with that portion of the progress.

The inner progressbar() function itself is good standalone as well if you want other portions of your script to control the progressbar. For instance, sending 'progressbar 10 "Creating directory tree";' will display:

```
[#######                                     ] (10%) Creating directory tree
```

Of course it will be nicely psychedelic though...

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then echo "x is \"time in seconds\" and z is \"message\""; echo "Usage: progressbar x z"; exit; fi
progressbar() {
        local loca=$1; local loca2=$2;
        declare -a bgcolors; declare -a fgcolors;
        for i in {40..46} {100..106}; do
                bgcolors+=("$i")
        done
        for i in {30..36} {90..96}; do
                fgcolors+=("$i")
        done
        local u=$(( 50 - loca ));
        local y; local t;
        local z; z=$(printf '%*s' "$u");
        local w=$(( loca * 2 ));
        local bouncer=".oO°Oo.";
        for ((i=0;i<loca;i++)); do
                t="${bouncer:((i%${#bouncer})):1}"
                bgcolor="\\E[${bgcolors[RANDOM % 14]}m \\033[m"
                y+="$bgcolor";
        done
        fgcolor="\\E[${fgcolors[RANDOM % 14]}m"
        echo -ne " $fgcolor$t$y$z$fgcolor$t \\E[96m(\\E[36m$w%\\E[96m)\\E[92m $fgcolor$loca2\\033[m\r"
};
timeprogress() {
        local loca="$1"; local loca2="$2";
        loca=$(bc -l <<< scale=2\;"$loca/50")
        for i in {1..50}; do
                progressbar "$i" "$loca2";
                sleep "$loca";
        done
        printf "\n"
};
timeprogress "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: *nicely psychedelic* is a slight understatement. Interesting approach. One note, there is no need to force the interpretations of escape sequences with `echo` to generate a `newline` (e.g. `echo -e "\n"`) a simple `echo ""` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're right about echo however I tend to steer away from double quotations "" for aesthetic reasons. I like to "see" the newline (\n).

Comment: Fair enough. If the `'\n'` is for aesthetics, then `printf "\n"` is your friend `:)`

Answer (score -1):

First execute the process to the background, then watch it's running status frequently,that was running print the pattern and again check it status was running or not;

Using while loop to watch the status of the process frequently.

use the pgrep or any other command to watch and getting running status of a process.

if using pgrep redirect the unnecessary output to /dev/null as needed.

**Code:**

```
sleep 12&
while pgrep sleep &> /dev/null;do echo -en "#";sleep 0.5;done
```

This "#" will printed until sleep terminate,this method used to implement the progress bar for progress time of program.

you can also use this method to the commands to shell scripts for analyze it process time as visual.

**BUG:**
 this pgrep method doesn't works in all situations,unexpectedly the another process was running with same name, the while loop does not end.

so getting the process running status by specify it's PID, using
may the process can available with some commands,

the command ***ps a*** will list all the process with id,you need *grep* to find-out the pid of the specified process

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to track progress based on the number of lines a command output against a target number of lines from a previous run:

```
#!/bin/bash
function lines {
  local file=$1
  local default=$2
  if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    wc -l $file | awk '{print $1}';
  else
    echo $default
  fi
}

function bar {
  local items=$1
  local total=$2
  local size=$3
  percent=$(($items*$size/$total % $size))
  left=$(($size-$percent))
  chars=$(local s=$(printf "%${percent}s"); echo "${s// /=}")
  echo -ne "[$chars>";
  printf "%${left}s"
  echo -ne ']\r'
}

function clearbar {
  local size=$1
  printf " %${size}s  "
  echo -ne "\r"
}

function progress {
  local pid=$1
  local total=$2
  local file=$3

  bar 0 100 50
  while [[ "$(ps a | awk '{print $1}' | grep $pid)" ]]; do
    bar $(lines $file 0) $total 50
    sleep 1
  done
  clearbar 50
  wait $pid
  return $?
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
target=$(lines build.log 1000)
(mvn clean install > build.log 2>&1) &
progress $! $target build.log
```

It outputs a progress bar that looks something like this:

```
[===============================================>   ]
```

The bar grows as the number of lines output reaches the target. If the number of lines exceeds the target, the bar starts over (hopefully the target is good).

BTW: I'm using bash on Mac OSX. I based this code on a spinner from [mariascio](https://github.com/marascio/bash-tips-and-tricks/tree/master/showing-progress-with-a-bash-spinner).

Answer (score -3):

To make a tar progress bar

```
tar xzvf pippo.tgz |xargs -L 19 |xargs -I@ echo -n "."
```

Where "19" is the number of files in the tar divided the length of the intended progress bar.
Example: the .tgz contains 140 files and you'll want a progress bar of 76 ".", you can put -L 2.

You'll need nothing else.

Comment: This is specific to `tar`, so unless the shell script only consist of `tar` command, it doesn't really apply to OP's case.

Comment: tar comes with a progress bar built-in, so a tar-specific answer isn't very helpful. Also, making the user divide number of files by length isn't very user-friendly. Try generalizing this into a more versatile function.

Answer (score -3):

Once I also had a busy script which was occupied for hours without showing any progress. So I implemented a function which mainly includes the techniques of the previous answers:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Updates the progress bar
# Parameters: 1. Percentage value
update_progress_bar()
{
  if [ $# -eq 1 ];
  then
    if [[ $1 == [0-9]* ]];
    then
      if [ $1 -ge 0 ];
      then
        if [ $1 -le 100 ];
        then
          local val=$1
          local max=100

          echo -n "["

          for j in $(seq $max);
          do
            if [ $j -lt $val ];
            then
              echo -n "="
            else
              if [ $j -eq $max ];
              then
                echo -n "]"
              else
                echo -n "."
              fi
            fi
          done

          echo -ne " "$val"%\r"

          if [ $val -eq $max ];
          then
            echo ""
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi
}

update_progress_bar 0
# Further (time intensive) actions and progress bar updates
update_progress_bar 100
```

Comment: You could roll up those first four ifs into a single if statement with a series of ANDs, since you don't have any specific code within any of them:
`if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [[ $1 == [0-9]* ]] && [ $1 -ge 0 ] && [ $1 -le 100 ];`

You could also circumvent the for loops and shorten your code with printf and command substitution:
`printf "[";
printf "%.0=" $(seq $val);
printf "%.0." $(seq $[ $val+1 ] $max);
printf "] %s%%\r" $val;`

Answer (score -5):

I had the same thing to do today and based on Diomidis answer, here is how I did it (linux debian 6.0.7).
Maybe, that could help you :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "getting script inode"
inode=`ls -i ./script.sh | cut -d" " -f1`
echo $inode

echo "getting the script size"
size=`cat script.sh | wc -c`
echo $size

echo "executing script"
./script.sh &
pid=$!
echo "child pid = $pid"

while true; do
        let offset=`lsof -o0 -o -p $pid | grep $inode | awk -F" " '{print $7}' | cut -d"t" -f 2`
        let percent=100*$offset/$size
        echo -ne " $percent %\r"
done
```

Comment: can you explain what offset calculate .

Comment: When I start this script as root, I get the error: `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /home/rubo77/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
`

Comment: And, I get the error: `progressbar: Zeile 17: let: offset=: Syntax Fehler: Operator erwartet. (Fehlerverursachendes Zeichen ist \"=\").` if I call this script `progressbar.sh` and call it with `cd /tmp/; echo "sleep 5">script.sh; bash progressbar.sh` on Ubuntu 13.04