# On enter action?

Tags: python, key, action, enter

Hey I'm working on a python project that requires an action that takes a couple minutes. The thing is since it takes a couple minutes I'd like the user to be able to press enter to see the current status of the action. How can I do this in Python 2?

Comment: Is this a command line project or one with UI? Can you post some code of how you launch the background task?

Comment: It's a command line project. And it's a simple port scanner. I just want it to write which port it's scanning when the user presses enter.

Comment: The simplest way would be to use threads I guess. One thread scanning ports and the other waiting for user input.

Comment: Why don't you just display a [progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/)?

Comment: A progress bar is a good idea but I use a for loop so I have a lot of problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Space_C0wb0y is right, a progress bar is a good solution. However, this demonstrates one way to do what you asked for. Some code pinched from here: [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/)

```
import fcntl, os, sys

# make stdin a non-blocking file
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

def enter_pressed():
    data = sys.stdin.read(1)
    return bool(data)

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    if enter_pressed():
        print(i)
```