# Clear console to get a single row of logging in terminal Python

Tags: python, logging, console

I'm trying to display a single line of logging in the console instead of have a bunh of lines for every single update.

I think with an example is easy to understand. I have a while True cycle like:

```
logging.info("Starting")
while True:
    data = checknewdata()
    logging.info("Data " + data)
```

I would like that the line logging.info("Data " + data) appears just once on the console but that it updates at every cycle with the new value so, instead of having:

```
Data 1
Data 2
Data 5
Data 8
```

I would have just a single line `Data x` with `x` actually varying with the new values

I've tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984684/display-only-one-logging-line-removing-the-previous-ones) or adding `sys.stdout.flush()` but it doesn't work

Any suggestion?

I'm using PyCharm and Grep Console, both on the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cls `cls` command:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

This should clear the console for you.

Comment: I don't want to clear the whole console, just the last line

Comment: Also, it doesn't work, it prints a strange symbol