# Removing/Replacing Prints in Python 3

Tags: python, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)
>   [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

So I'm working on a basic program and I'm trying to make two things:

1. A Loading... text line where the dots increase in this manner:

   Loading.

   Loading..

   Loading...

   Loading.

   Loading..

   Loading...
2. An increasing percent in one line:

   1% Complete...

   3% Complete...

   etc.

So, my question is how do I remove/replace printed text? I want these things to happen on one line. For the first example, how do I replace the 3 dots with just 1, or just erase the 2 on the end (without going to the next line)? For the second example, how do I make the percent increase while staying on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for i in range(100):
...    time.sleep(1)
...    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" %i)    # or print >> sys.stdout, "\r%d%%" %i,
...    sys.stdout.flush()
...
```

This will help you with the percentage.