# Print over last line in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

When using `wget` in a Linux terminal, the last line printed in the terminal is being overwritten as the download progresses, to reflect the progress.

Can I overwrite the last line of the terminal in Python? (targeting Linux only)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar/3162864 Has been answered here

Comment: related: [Text Progress Bar in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`blessings` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/) to write on the last line in a terminal on Linux:

```
from blessings import Terminal # $ pip install blessings

t = Terminal()
with t.location(0, t.height - 1):
    print('This is at the bottom.')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use escape sequences.

You might be familiar with "\n" for new line.
There's also "\b" for backspace and "\r" for carriage return.

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\r{}".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: this doesn't overwrite the *last* line in the terminal. It can overwrite the current line.

Comment: You're right. I assumed that the current line is the last line.