# there is a way to detect if '\r' work or not?

Tags: python, char, escaping, python-idle, tqdm

I have a script to download some files with `urllib.request.urlretrieve` and I use [`tqdm`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) for my progress bar and that work fine, except when I use in the IDLE because there the others control characters like `'\r'` or `'\b'` don't work properly and as result the output is ugly

that is

IDLE

```
>>> print('abc\rXXX')
abc\rXXX
>>> print('abc\b\b\bXXX')
abc\b\b\bXXX
>>>
```

terminal/cmd

```
>>> print('abc\rXXX')
XXX
>>> print('abc\b\b\bXXX')
XXX
>>>
```

my question is, how I can detect when `'\r'` will work properly??

so I can do something like this

```
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_gui
if control_char_work_fine():
    progress_bar = tqdm
else:
    progress_bar = tqdm_qui
```

or if that is no possible how to detect when I am in the IDLE?

Comment: The [`curses` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) lets you query various things about a terminal, but you'd have to call `curses.initscr()` first, which is rather.. invasive in a terminal.

Comment: Don't have `IDLE`, but what does `import os ; os.environ['TERM']` print in that terminal?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson on windows it give a `KeyError`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson in the IDLE and in the `cmd` I get a `keyError`, in terminal I get `'xterm'`

Comment: I think I've found it, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135271/322909

Comment: @MartijnPieters in windows I get a `ImportError: No module named '_curses' in ubuntu using the IDLE I get a error `_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal` and in the terminal, after I call that I can not do anithing else, so I closed...

Comment: @John nice, that work in python 2,3 windows and ubuntu

Comment: Previous discussion of the \r issue is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895864/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-idle-when-using-tqdm.  I think `'idlelib' in sys.modules` is the best test for 'running under IDLE'.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy yep, that was my previous question on the subject