# Python: simple progress bar on subprocess call

Tags: python, progress-bar

i have a simple write to file code, (one.py)

one.py

```
from time import sleep
f = open("test.txt","w") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
sleep(1)
f.write("I am a test file.")
sleep (2)
f.write("Maybe someday, he will promote me to a real file.")
sleep (1)
f.write("Man, I long to be a real file")
sleep (1)
f.write("and hang out with all my new real file friends.")
f.close()
```

subpro.py

```
import subprocess

def oneCall():
    subprocess.call(['python','one.py'])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Writing Data"
    oneCall()
```

when i run subpro.py, the indicator will show like it hang, is there any way i can change it in to progress bar? so that the user will know that there are actually progress in the background?

Answer (score 1):

hi below are my solution. but unfortunately the loading only says done after one.py and two.py is completed.

how to make it

done (one.py)

done (two.py)

```
import subprocess
import time, sys
import threading
def oneCall():
    subprocess.call(['python','one.py'])

def twoCall():
    subprocess.call(['python','two.py'])


class progress_bar_loading(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
            global stop
            global kill
            print 'Loading....  ',
            sys.stdout.flush()
            i = 0
            while stop != True:
                    if (i%4) == 0: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b/')
                    elif (i%4) == 1: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b-')
                    elif (i%4) == 2: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b\\')
                    elif (i%4) == 3: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b|')

                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    i+=1

            if kill == True: 
                print '\b\b\b\b ABORT!',
            else: 
                print '\b\b\b done!',


kill = False      
stop = False
p = progress_bar_loading()
p.start()

try:
    #anything you want to run.
    oneCall()
    twoCall()
    time.sleep(1)
    stop = True
except KeyboardInterrupt or EOFError:
         kill = True
         stop = True
```

Answer (score 0):

There already exist Python libraries which do exactly that like [progress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress) or [progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar).

You can also implement it yourself, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3160819/811708).

Basically the idea is to `write` and `flush` the command line, so that a progress bar will appear to be moving.

```
Processing |###########                     | 30%
```