# tqdm in Jupyter Notebook prints new progress bars repeatedly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I am using `tqdm` to print progress in a script I'm running in a Jupyter notebook. I am printing all messages to the console via `tqdm.write()`. However, this still gives me a skewed output like so:

[image]

That is, each time a new line has to be printed, a new progress bar is printed on the next line. This does not happen when I run the script via terminal. How can I solve this?

Comment: Actually, when I use `tqdm_notebook`, I can even do normal `print`s, and it doesn't affect the progress bar.

Comment: an alternative is to use this `progressbar` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar/34482761#34482761

Comment: Check also: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/375

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Try using `tqdm.notebook.tqdm` instead of `tqdm`, as outlined [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm#ipython-jupyter-integration).

This could be as simple as changing your import to:

`from tqdm.notebook import tqdm`

**EDIT:** After testing, it seems that `tqdm` actually works fine in 'text mode' in Jupyter notebook. It's hard to tell because you haven't provided a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it looks like your problem is caused by a print statement in each iteration. The print statement is outputting a number (~0.89) in between each status bar update, which is messing up the output. Try removing the print statement.

Comment: I haven't used a `print()` statement, I used `tqdm.write()`. However, `tqdm_notebook` gives good results. Thanks : )

Comment: Do you know if it supports Python 3.6? I've not had luck with this

Comment: What error are you getting? It works fine for me. Impossible to help with so little info... Have you [enabled ipywidgets in jupyer](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html)? Have you just plain `tqdm`, rather than `tqdm_notebook`? This works well with Python 3.6 and Jupyter 1.0.0.

Comment: tqdm_notebook from tqdm 4.19.4 is working for me on Python 3.6, Jupyter notebook 5.0.0, and ipywidgets 7.0.3.

Comment: has anyone gotten `tqdm.tqdm.pandas()` to work with `tqdm.tqdm_notebook`? I'd like to use both.

Comment: I am not sure if it really helps, but I just faced the same issue - with a for loop. I tried tqdm_notebook but its not giving the progressbar (I am in Python 3.6). On re-trying with tqdm itself however, it worked again. So though I don't know the reason, just retrying with tqdm has helped me.

Comment: @justacluelessnewbie you broke the import

Comment: actually made it worse for me.. now there are 2 newlines after each iteration rather than one...

Comment: This seems to be an easiest way: `from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm`

Comment: This works for me in Windows, but in Linux it doesn't show progress bar (just a weird text like Hbox...)

Comment: When I do `from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm` and then try to do `tqdm.write("stuff")` I get: `AttributeError: module 'tqdm' has no attribute 'write'`

Answer (score 56):

This is an alternative answer for the case where *tqdm_notebook* doesn't work for you.

### Given the following example:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

values = range(3)
with tqdm(total=len(values)) as pbar:
    for i in values:
        pbar.write('processed: %d' %i)
        pbar.update(1)
        sleep(1)
```

The output would look something like this (progress would show up red):

```
  0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
processed: 1
 67%|██████▋   | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  1.99it/s]
processed: 2
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.53it/s]
processed: 3
```

The problem is that the output to *stdout* and *stderr* are processed asynchronously and separately in terms of new lines.

If say Jupyter receives on stderr the first line and then the "processed" output on stdout. Then once it receives an output on stderr to update the progress, it wouldn't go back and update the first line as it would only update the last line. Instead it will have to write a new line.

### Workaround 1, writing to stdout

One workaround would be to output both to stdout instead:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

values = range(3)
with tqdm(total=len(values), file=sys.stdout) as pbar:
    for i in values:
        pbar.write('processed: %d' % (1 + i))
        pbar.update(1)
        sleep(1)
```

The output will change to (no more red):

```
processed: 1   | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
processed: 2   | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
processed: 3   | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  1.99it/s]
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.53it/s]
```

Here we can see that Jupyter doesn't seem to clear until the end of the line. We could add another workaround for that by adding spaces. Such as:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

values = range(3)
with tqdm(total=len(values), file=sys.stdout) as pbar:
    for i in values:
        pbar.write('processed: %d%s' % (1 + i, ' ' * 50))
        pbar.update(1)
        sleep(1)
```

Which gives us:

```
processed: 1                                                  
processed: 2                                                  
processed: 3                                                  
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.53it/s]
```

## Workaround 2, set description instead

It might in general be more straight forward not to have two outputs but update the description instead, e.g.:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

values = range(3)
with tqdm(total=len(values), file=sys.stdout) as pbar:
    for i in values:
        pbar.set_description('processed: %d' % (1 + i))
        pbar.update(1)
        sleep(1)
```

With the output (description updated while it's processing):

```
processed: 3: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.53it/s]
```

### Conclusion

You can mostly get it to work fine with plain tqdm. But if *tqdm_notebook* works for you, just use that (but then you'd probably not read that far).

Comment: an alternative is to use this `progressbar` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34482761/1207193

Answer (score 37):

Most of the answers are outdated now. Better if you import **tqdm** correctly.

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
```

[image]

Comment: It changed again:
`TqdmDeprecationWarning: This function will be removed in tqdm==5.0.0
Please use tqdm.notebook.tqdm instead of tqdm.tqdm_notebook`

Answer (score 33):

To complete oscarbranson's answer: it's possible to automatically pick console or notebook versions of progress bar depending on where it's being run from:

```
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
```

More info can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#ipython-jupyter-integration)

Comment: That's great, thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 21):

None of the above works for me. I find that running the following sorts this issue after error (It just clears all the instances of progress bars in the background):

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

# blah blah your code errored

tqdm._instances.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you! 
However it throws and error if no instances exists. Still want to use it with scripts and Hydrogen IDE. Here is my code.

`try:
    # Avoids problem on notebooks / Hydrogen IDE
    tqdm.tqdm._instances.clear()
except Exception:
    pass`

Comment: Yup it will throw an exception if no instance exists. Is there an issue with your try except approach?

Answer (score 19):

If the other tips here don't work and - just like me - you're using the `pandas` integration through `progress_apply`, you can let `tqdm` handle it:

```
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df.progress_apply(row_function, axis=1)
```

The main point here lies in the `tqdm.autonotebook` module. As stated in [their instructions for use in IPython Notebooks](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#ipythonjupyter-integration), this makes `tqdm` choose between progress bar formats used in Jupyter notebooks and Jupyter consoles - for a reason still lacking further investigations on my side, the specific format chosen by `tqdm.autonotebook` works smoothly in `pandas`, while all others didn't, for `progress_apply` specifically.

Comment: Note that using `tqdm.autonotebook` results in a `TqdmExperimentalWarning` as tqdm doesn't know if it's a jupyter notebook or jupyter console. Use `tqdm.auto` instead to suppress this. See https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#ipython-jupyter-integration

Answer (score 7):

For everyone who is on windows and couldn't solve the duplicating bars issue with any of the solutions mentioned here. I had to install the `colorama` package as stated in [tqdm's known issues](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues) which fixed it.

```
pip install colorama
```

Try it with this example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

for _ in tqdm(range(5), "All", ncols = 80, position = 0):
    for _ in tqdm(range(100), "Sub", ncols = 80, position = 1, leave = False):
        sleep(0.01)
```

Which will produce something like:

```
All:  60%|████████████████████████                | 3/5 [00:03<00:02,  1.02s/it]
Sub:  50%|██████████████████▌                  | 50/100 [00:00<00:00, 97.88it/s]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `Python 3.9.2` and `tqdm==4.62.3`:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

for item in tqdm(list_of_items):
    do_something(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

`tqdm` automatically loads the fitting progress bar, either for normal code or interactive environments via

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use tqdm_notebook**

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

x=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in tqdm(range(0,len(x))):

    print(x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed to update ipywidgets to get rid of the extra printing when using regular `from tqdm import tqdm`.

Answer (score -1):

**Another Example for Progress Bar using tqdm**

```
from tqdm import tqdm

my_list = list(range(100))
with tqdm(total=len(my_list)) as pbar:
    for x in my_list:
       pbar.update(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue.