# Using multiple bars

Tags: python, tqdm

I would like to have two independent progress bars.

This is a minimal example where if I use two bars they are not updated properly. Instead, new bars are created.

```
import time
from tqdm import *

pbar1 = tqdm(total=100)
pbar2 = tqdm(total=200)

for i in range(10):
    pbar1.update(10)
    pbar2.update(20)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When running the example. I get something like:

```
  0%|          | 0/100 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
 20%|██        | 20/100 [00:01<00:04, 19.97it/s]
 30%|███       | 30/100 [00:02<00:04, 15.36it/s]
 40%|████      | 40/100 [00:03<00:04, 13.23it/s]
 50%|█████     | 50/100 [00:04<00:04, 12.05it/s]
 60%|██████    | 60/100 [00:05<00:03, 11.35it/s]
 70%|███████   | 70/100 [00:06<00:02, 10.90it/s]
 80%|████████  | 80/100 [00:07<00:01, 10.61it/s]
 90%|█████████ | 90/100 [00:08<00:00, 10.42it/s]
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:09<00:00, 10.28it/s]
100%|██████████| 200/200 [00:09<00:00, 20.57it/s]
```

As shown, updating does not work properly and adds new bars.
Is it possible to have two independent bars that update properly?

Comment: For everyone on windows, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61068454/4440823) in a different thread. Short version: Install the `colorama` package as stated in [tqdm's known issues](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues): pip install colorama

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try using the `position` parameter when initialising the bars:

```
pbar1 = tqdm(total=100, position=1)
pbar2 = tqdm(total=200, position=0)
```

From the [tqdm GitHub page](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm):

> position : int, optional
>
> Specify the line offset to print this bar (starting from 0) Automatic if unspecified. Useful to manage multiple bars at once (eg, from threads).

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me: `from tqdm import tqdm;
def c():  for _ in tqdm([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], position=0): for _ in tqdm([1, 2, 3, 4], position=1): pass` still produces multiple lines. I am using Python 3.6.8 and I ran this in IDLE.

Comment: Also have the issue with `tqdm_notebook`

Comment: but in this case you produce a new tqdm bar at each iteration of your first loop. This solution would work if you have to independent loops, like 2 threads/process, so that each bar is created once only.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/0ec48a2c11ce3b6995c963f72fec4969/pytorch-1-7-0-why-tqdm-prints-to-a-newline.ipynb) I have some examples of nested progress bar, examples of `tqdm` and some issues I have with it in general; from which I highlight the following code snippet that yields to two nice **nested progress bars**.

```
def test48():
  with tqdm.notebook.trange(3, position=0, desc='Outter') as outter_range:
    for i in outter_range:
      leave = i == len(outter_range) - 1
      for _ in tqdm.notebook.trange(3, position=1, leave=leave, desc='Inner'):
        sleep(.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `tqdm._get_free_pos()` to dynamically handle the position of the progress bars. You can have an arbitrarily complicated nesting of progress bars and they won't overwrite each other.

The following example should give an idea of how bars can be nastily nested.

```
total_sum = 0
for i in trange(np.random.randint(10), position=tqdm._get_free_pos(), leave=False):
    if not (i % 5):
       for j in trange(np.random.randint(10), position=tqdm._get_free_pos(), leave=False):
          if (i < j):
              for k in trange(np.random.randint(10 + i), position=tqdm._get_free_pos(), leave=False):
                  if (i == k):
                      do_something_foo(i, j, k)
                  else:
                      do_something_else(i, j, k)
          else:
              for k in trange(np.random.randint(10 + j), position=tqdm._get_free_pos(), leave=False):
                  if (i > k):
                      do_something_foo(i, j, k)
                  else:
                      do_something_else(i, j, k)
```