# How to "flush" tqdm progress bar explicitly?

Tags: python, pycharm, flush, tqdm

I often see, that [`tqdm` progress bar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) is broken by other print, like:

```
 93%|█████████▎| 28/30 [00:02<00:00, 13.44it/s]Subject S9
100%|██████████| 30/30 [00:02<00:00, 12.94it/s]
 93%|█████████▎| 28/30 [00:02<00:00, 11.49it/s]Pickling...
100%|██████████| 30/30 [00:02<00:00, 11.47it/s]
```

Here only 2 progress bars should be shown. Nevertheless succeeded, printing of some text interrupts progress bar at high percentage and the rest of it is printed out afterwards.

Is it possible to "flush" progress bar somehow?

I read, that `tqdm` prints to `stderr` by default and tried to flush it

```
sys.stderr.flush()
```

but this didn't helped.

All above is happened in PyCharm console simulation, so it can be related with this.

Comment: Test outside PyCharm ;). from my experience the console that PyCharm offers has some issues sometimes.

Answer (score 21):

By default, `tqdm` prints to `stderr`.  Your statements `Subject...` and `Pickling...` are printing to `stdout`.  By default, those two streams are not in sync.

If you want `tqdm` to be in sync with `print`s, route `tqdm` to `stdout` instead of `stderr`.  This is achieved via:

```
tqdm(range(50), file=sys.stdout)
```

You would then not need to flush stdout.

Answer (score 6):

To explicitly flush at a time, use `refresh()`. To explicitly flush at the end, if tqdm gets stuck, you should call `tqdm.close(self)`.
Example:

```
import time
i_range=tqdm(range(5))
for i in i_range:
        i_range.refresh()
        time.sleep(1)
i_range.close()
```

More complicated, nested loop example:

```
progress = tqdm(range(5*3 ) )
for i in range(5):
    print '============================='
    for j in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        progress.update()
        progress.refresh()
progress.close()
```

Note that [tqdm has parameters](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/) related to refresh freq:

> mininterval : float, optional Minimum progress display update interval
>   [default: 0.1] seconds. maxinterval : float, optional Maximum progress
>   display update interval [default: 10] seconds.

Comment: Could you explain your second example, please? You create a `tqdm` object but you don't iterate over it—what happens here?

Comment: Instead of iterating over it, I am using .update() This similart to, instead of iterating on an iterable, calling its  .next() method explicitly in a loop... Every time I call `progress.update()`, it advances the tqdm object by one... The range of the tqdm object is the first loop size times the second loop size... I added the `refresh()` command so that the updated value is shown in the screen.

Comment: (Also, the range is (5*3 ) because the outer loop is repeated 5 times, and the inner 3)

Comment: Aha; seems very useful!

Comment: @Filip: Sorry for rejecting your changes, however, from a quick look, they create a (pottentially better, however rather differend) answer. I propose you post your code as a new answer as I feel It may have a lot to contribute (and it will also give the reputation to you instead of me ;) )

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet (since tqdm kinda takes over the output) is to use

`tqdm.write`

so if you have a progress bar you can use that to try and print during like this:

```
In [19]:     from tqdm import tqdm
    ...:     import time
    ...:
    ...:     for i in tqdm(xrange(50)):
    ...:         if i & 0x1 == 0:
    ...:           tqdm.write(str(i))
    ...:           time.sleep(0.5)
    ...:
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
 14%|███████████▌                                                                       | 7/50 [01:50<11:16, 15.73s/it]---------------------------------------------------------------------------             | 11/50 [00:03<00:10,  3.62it/s]
```

Which should end up printing and keep the bar at the bottom separately.

if you would like to refresh the bar explicitly you can try and use `tqdm.refresh` in addition:

```
In [16]: gen = tqdm(xrange(50))
  0%|                                                                                           | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
In [17]: for i in gen:
    ...:     if i & 0x1 == 0:
    ...:       print str(i)
    ...:       gen.refresh()
    ...:       time.sleep(0.5)
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:
0
  2%|█▋                                                                                 | 1/50 [00:01<01:17,  1.59s/it]2
  6%|████▉                                                                              | 3/50 [00:02<00:55,  1.19s/it]4
 10%|████████▎                                                                          | 5/50 [00:02<00:40,  1.10it/s]6
 14%|███████████▌                                                                       | 7/50 [00:03<00:30,  1.41it/s]8
 14%|███████████▌                                                                       | 7/50 [00:03<
```

But as you can see without using tqdm.write you still end up with characters beside the bar being printed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to force the output : tqdm.write is waiting a string, and allows to specify the end.

```
for sentences_db, itdqm in zip(sentences_dbs, tqdm(range(len(sentences_dbs)))):
    tqdm.write(itdqm.__str__(), end='')
```

You can force the outputs with the file attribute (ie: file=sys.stderr), because when it's very quick, the outputs has a direction problem (stdout instead of stderr). Import the sys module to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try The Function Called

> tqdm.clear

But... Before That Make An Object Or...

I'll Show You The Code :-

```
from tqdm import tqdm
bar = tqdm(yourList)
for i in bar:
    #Do Stuff :)
    #But Right Where You Wanna Make It Go And Come Back Do This :-
    bar.clear()
```

I Hope It Works :)

Comment: The `clear` method works well when you are not calling `print` inside your loop.  If you are, you will still get weird behavior like OP reported.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
print(f'First print')
for x in tqdm(some_list):
    some_operation = 1+1

# Surround next print with some sleepy time to have give the previous tqdm bar time to finish
time.sleep(0.5)
print(f'Second print')
time.sleep(0.5)

for y in tqdm(some_other_list):
    some_other_operation = 1+3+3+7
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to help with what works for me.

```
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
print('This is done')
sleep(.5)
for i in tqdm(range(0,30), total = (30), desc = 'Subject S9'):
    sleep(.3)
    sys.stdout.flush()
sleep(.5)

for i in tqdm(range(0,30), total = (30), desc = 'Pickling...'):
    sleep(.3)
    sys.stdout.flush()

sleep(.5)
```

The output would be:

```
This is done
Subject S9: 100%|██████████| 30/30 [00:09<00:00,  3.30it/s]
Pickling...: 100%|██████████| 30/30 [00:09<00:00,  3.30it/s]
```

Just putting sleep() between each iteration would help to give it time to end the process before the next iteration.
Hope it helps. CMIIW :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering exactly the question **how to flush tqdm progress bar** (when you want no repeating of bars or some bugs):

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
# YOUR CODE
tqdm._instances.clear()
```

In Jupyter notebook problem can be solved by these approaches:
[tqdm in Jupyter Notebook prints new progress bars repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212810/tqdm-in-jupyter-notebook-prints-new-progress-bars-repeatedly)

Answer (score 0):

Your `tqdm` progress bars may be a bit unfilled due to how Python loops and such are structured. This should not happen with correctly structured loops, but creating such loops is not always possible, especially when using third-party libraries.

After your operation is complete, you can check how much the progress bar is unfilled and call `update()` for the remaining amount.

```py
progress_bar.update(progress_bar.total - progress_bar.n)
```

This seems to be the cleanest working approach, especially with various Jupyter Notebooks and HTML-based progress bars.

Answer (score 0):

Flush, in this context, means printing the contents of the buffer to the console. Since the output is already on the console, it's not going to solve your problem.

tqdm assumes the cursor hasn't moved since it last wrote, so if there is output to the console, it will output the update wherever the cursor happens to be. Even if you redirect all other output through tqdm.write(), it just clears the lines with progress bars, writes the output and redraws the progress bars. It's extremely inefficient and breaks if you have too much output.

I'd suggest using a different progress bar library, like [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) that handles printing natively. It does this by changing the scroll region and only drawing below the scroll region.

Since you mentioned you're using PyCharm. There is a long standing [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252747/) in the Pycharm terminal, that may cause issues for you with Enlighten, but it will work fine with other terminals.