# Is there a way to make a progress bar and update within a helper function?

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

Still learning tqdm, is there a way to make a progress bar and update within a helper function?

I have checked out other questions, but I couldn't find the answer, like
[How to "flush" tqdm progress bar explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862715/how-to-flush-tqdm-progress-bar-explicitly)

What I have also tried:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
def helper_function(progress, outer_total):
    for i in range(100):
        # do some work
        time.sleep(1)
        progress.update(1/outer_total/100)
    return

def main_function():
    with tqdm(total=1000, desc="Main loop", unit="iter") as progress:
        for j in range(10):
            # do some work
            time.sleep(1)
            helper_function(progress, 1000)

main_function()

> Main loop:   0%|          | 0.00999999999999976/1000 [00:00<01:37, 10.22iter/s]
```

Not really what I wanted.

1. Somehow it's stuck at infinite loop and always 0%
2. I pretty much just want `%`, how do I remove the other things on the progress bar?

Any help would be great.