# Newline created after each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I'm using `tqdm` combined with Pandas on Jupyter notebooks.

I have a Pandas dataframe `df`.
When i use `df.progress_apply`, new lines are printed instead of updating only one.

This is what I currently do :

```
tqdm.pandas(desc="Computing MONTH...")
df["MONTH"] = df.progress_apply(compute_month, axis=1)
```

[image: A newline is made after each print]

My question is not a duplicate of this question : [tqdm in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212810/tqdm-in-jupyter-notebook)

because they said to use `tqdm_notebook` instead of `tqdm`. 
I can't use `tqdm_notebook` as I need to implement `df.progress_apply`.

I can't reproduce this issue on a minimal example because my code is too heavy.

Here is an issue in Github related of this problem but couldn't help me : https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/375

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
tqdm_notebook().pandas()
```

And that will do!