# tqdm not counting iterations in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I am using `tqdm` to display progress of iterations. However it doesn't work properly in my `jupyter notebook` environment.

I can do

```
from tqdm import tqdm
a = 0
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    a += i

print(a)
```

with output

[image]

This however has a problem with `print` statements in the loop ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212810/tqdm-in-jupyter-notebook-prints-new-progress-bars-repeatedly)).
When I do

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
a = 0
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    a += i

print(a)
```

I get

[image]

I.e. the iterations are executed but tqdm does not account for them.

Any idea how to fix this or what the problem might be?

The output of `jupyter --version` is

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.20.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.11
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.2
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

**EDIT**
The problem seems to be bound to MacOS (I am running 10.15.7), since I do not observe it on CentOS.

Besides that I tried I updated my conda environment

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.2
ipython          : 7.20.0
ipykernel        : 5.5.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.11
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.2
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

on python 3.8.8. (I also tried on 3.7.10).
[This issue](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1120) discusses something similar and the problems seems to be related to `ipywidgets`.

Comment: I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1149

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Jupyter Lab (3.0.9) and this worked for me:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager \ 
&& jupyter lab
```

Even though `ipywidgets` should install the labextension automatically, it was not listed in `jupyter labextension list`. When I install it manually, the progress bar works.

For classic notebooks, the `ipywidgets` [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-in-classic-jupyter-notebook) mention this:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Comment: Turns out, that my environment was messed up for some reason. Even though I had `widgetsnbextension` and `ipywidgets` installed it was not properly recognized. After a clean install of my environment everything works as expected now.