# Python progress bar confusion, how to add progress bar to already existing loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, progress-bar

After looking at the following question with regards to Python Progress bars, I am still confused:
[Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)

I am new to Python and I am trying to add a progress bar to a script I created which runs a for loop. The loop takes a significant amount of time to process so I want the progress bar to show when the loop is running. The part that confuses me is, do I have set to up a loop inside of a loop in order to implement a progress bar? Here is a sample of my for loop from my code:

```
for member in members:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/member?id="+str(member) 

    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    member_check = json.loads(api_response.text)

    member_status = member_check.get("response")
```

Do I need to include the code to add a progress bar INTO this loop or does it have to be included outside of the loop? Thanks.

Update: I mention the progressbar library here but I am open to suggestions of other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to `print '-'` at the end of the loop. This prints one hyphen for each iteration of the for loop.

If you instead wanted to always print out 100 hyphens, 1 hyphen for each 'percent' then you might do something like `print '-'*(100/len(members))`, with an extra check for adding extra dashes to the last iteration for an even 100.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think this is the info I was looking for. More specifically, I was interested in using some type of progress bar library (like "progressbar" for example) but I am confused where the code needs to be inserted relative to my FOR loop that I have included as an example above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy with the [enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten) library. Just create a progress bar before the loop and update it with each instance of the loop. Using the manager, you could have additional progress bars for other parts of your program.

```
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=len(members), desc="Checking status", unit='members')

for member in members:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/member?id="+str(member)
    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}
    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    member_check = json.loads(api_response.text)
    member_status = member_check.get("response")
    pbar.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with [*atpbar*](https://github.com/alphatwirl/atpbar#atpbar) as long as `members` in your code has a length.

You only need to wrap `members` with `atpbar`:

```py
from atpbar import atpbar

⋮

for member in atpbar(members):
    ⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tqdm library.

You only need to modify your loop to include a counter, see this example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
startTime = time.clock()
totalCount = len(members)
for index, member in enumerate(members):
    stopTime = time.clock()
    statusBarText = tqdm.format_meter(index + 1,
                                      totalCount,
                                      stopTime - startTime,
                                      ncols=80,  # prints text 80 characters wide
                                      ascii=False)
    print(statusBarText, '\b' * 81, end='')
    startTime = time.clock()
    ... rest of the code in your loop ...
```