# python progression bar not in IDE but UI visually after running the program?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I saw many different codes and examples with progression bar. However none of them shows it in a UI format. It only shows it in the IDE which is not going to work if the user is not going to the IDE to run it. I don't have PYQT so I can't use it to create progress bar in that way. Are there any other ways to create progression bar that a user can see it after running the program, not via IDE.

Comment: I have a super basic text progress bar for the command line if you want that

Comment: Ok how does it show, the command line pops up and shows the % completed ?

Comment: Well if i run the program from a terminal, it appears in the terminal. I assume thats what you mean when you say you run the program not in an IDE

Comment: no run the program in executable (icon)

Comment: Well you could have a command line pop up when the executable is run, and show the text progress bar

Comment: Ok that is fine with me. how do you show that ?

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code for a *very* basic text progress bar:

```
class progressBar():
    def __init__(self, title, length=40):
        self.BAR_LENGTH = length
        self.title = title
        print('{}\t['.format(self.title) + ' ' * self.BAR_LENGTH + ']', end='')

    def update(self, val):
        # round from 0 to self.BAR_LENGTH
        bars = round(val * self.BAR_LENGTH)
        print('\r{}\t['.format(self.title) + '#' * bars + ' ' * (self.BAR_LENGTH - bars) + ']\t{0:.2f}%'.format(
            val * 100), end='')

    def close(self):
        print('')
```

You use it like this:

```
bar = progressBar("Text beside progress bar")
while myLoopCondition == True
     # loop that you want to show progress of
    ...
    bar.update(new percentage) # decimal number from 0-1
bar.close()
```

Whatever program you use to make your executable should have a way of displaying a terminal when you run the program.

You should look into getting pyqt for this though

Comment: That is not something I can answer with the info you gave. Put it wherever seems appropriate i guess

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tqdm library.

You only need to modify your loop to include a counter, see this example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

startTime = time.clock()
totalCount = len(listOfItems)
for index, item in enumerate(listOfItems):
    stopTime = time.clock()
    statusBarText = tqdm.format_meter(index + 1,
                                      totalCount,
                                      stopTime - startTime,
                                      ncols=80,  # prints text 80 characters wide
                                      ascii=False)
    print(statusBarText, '\b' * 81, end='')
    startTime = time.clock()
    ... rest of the code in your loop goes here ...
```