# Python ProgressBar in CLI

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I'm using Python 3.x and have downloaded the [progressbar2](https://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library; however, I'm struggling with how to use it in my program.  Everything works fine when there's a specified range but how do I get the progressbar to update in real-time with my own code?  I expect the progress bar to jump 20% at every iteration of the texts list with it being display first and refresh the progress as it prints out the results.

I've also found another question similar to mine on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar) but I'd prefer using the progressbar2 library since it's already there.  Consider the following:

```
import time
import progressbar

texts = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

def basic_widget_example (texts):

    widgets = [progressbar.Percentage (), progressbar.Bar ()]
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar (widgets = widgets, max_value = len (texts)).start ()
    for i in range (len (texts)):
        print (texts [i])
        time.sleep (0.1)
        bar.update (i + 1)
    bar.finish ()
```

Results:

```
N/A%|                                                                                                               |a
 20%|######################                                                                                         |b
 40%|############################################                                                                   |c
 60%|##################################################################                                             |d
 80%|########################################################################################                       |e
 100%|###############################################################################################################|
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
100%|#############################################################|
a
b                                                                                                                    
c                                                                                                                    
d                                                                                                                    
e
```

One solution is to create 2 for-loop but as you can see the progressbar display is no longer accurate or in sync with my tasks.  The progressbar will show 100% in less than a second even though my tasks may take 2 minutes to complete.  Any idea how to achieve this while being close to accurate as possible?

```
def basic_widget_example (texts):

    widgets = [progressbar.Percentage (), progressbar.Bar ()]
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar (widgets = widgets, max_value = len (texts)).start ()
    for i in range (len (texts)):
        # Do something
        time.sleep (0.1)
        bar.update (i + 1)
    bar.finish ()

    for text in texts:
        print (text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've misinterpreted the usage of the progress bar.  The progress bar is meant to let user know that calculation is taking place where there isn't a need communicating to the user.  It's useful in cases where some string manipulations or creating a list from a set of data is taking place behind the scene.  Once results is achieved and ready to be output onto the screen, there wouldn't be a need for a progress bar at that point.

As an example, I created a list of integers from 1 - 50, added 1 to it (background process), and appended it to another list which will be used to simulate output.

```
lst = [i for i in range (50)]
basic_widget_example (lst)

def basic_widget_example (lst):

    newlist = []

    widgets = [progressbar.Percentage (), progressbar.Bar ()]
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar (widgets = widgets, max_value = len (lst)).start ()
    for i in range (len (lst)):
        # Do something
        newlist = [x + 1 for x in lst]
        time.sleep (0.1)
        bar.update (i + 1)
    bar.finish ()

    print (newlist [:5])
```

Results:

```
100%|###############################################################################################################|
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The progress bar is being incremented with the length of the list which is 50 specified by the "max_value".  This will produce two '#' at every iteration.

It's also worth mentioning the time.sleep (value) correspond to the time it takes for the progress bar to complete.  In my example, 50 iterations * 0.1 seconds = 5 seconds.  This means the progressbar will be 100% completed in 5 seconds.  This is not real-time.  Further calculations is needed to come up with the sleep value if real-time.  One idea is to calculate the time it takes for each iteration or take an average and use that as a value for the time.sleep.