# How do I show a Progressbar when compressing and decompressing a folder in Python?

Tags: python

I want to create a progress bar that shows how much progress the compression program has made. I'm a newbie, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: please, take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider to add more details to your question

Comment: Did you consider searching for `python progress bar` online? Literally hundreds of results...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar) ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573445/add-progress-bar-to-a-python-function ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002085/python-to-print-out-status-bar-and-percentage ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a function which I have used within some of my projects. You can adapt it for your requirements:

```
import sys
import time
def update_progress(progress):
    barLength = 56    # specify the length of your progressbar
    status = ""
    if isinstance(progress, int):
        progress = float(progress)
    if not isinstance(progress, float):
        progress = 0
        status = "error: progress var must be float\r\n"
    if progress < 0:
        progress = 0
        status = "Halt...\r\n"
    if progress >= 1:
        progress = 1
        status = "Done...\r\n"
    block = int(round(barLength*progress))
    text = "\rProgress: [{0}] {1}%".format( "#"*block + "-"*(barLength-block), int(progress*100))    
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()       # clear screen to update progress
```

Call it:

```
update_progress(0.5)  # update to 50%
# do some processing #
# you might want to call sleep method if your processing doesn't take so long in order to smooth the progress update
time.sleep(2)         # wait for two seconds to see progress
update_progress(1);   # update to 100%
```

Output:

```
Progress: [########################################################] 100%
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) library. It's a very active project and there are examples on the github page on how to use it.

From the above site:

> Instantly make your loops show a smart progress meter - just wrap any
>   iterable with tqdm(iterable), and you're done!

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    ...
```

Its very easy to use and one that i would recommend.