# Progress indicator for Python that works with Visual Studio Code's debug console?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've tried a few of the answers provided in the [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar) question but run into different problems with each one.

Is there a known solution for using the vscode debug console to display progress in Python?

Here's an example of the output I tend to get.

[image: console output]

Answer (score 0):

The debug console does not display control characters that you would use for this ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27389)), which is why the answers on the question you reference don't work.