# Jupyter Notebooks not displaying progress bars

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, tqdm

I'm trying to get a progress bar going in Jupyter notebooks. This is a new computer and what I normally do doesn't seem to work:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
example_iter = [1,2,3,4,5]
for rec in tqdm_notebook(example_iter):
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Produces the following text output and doesn't show any progress bar

```
HBox(children=(IntProgress(value=0, max=5), HTML(value='')))
```

Similarly, this code:

```
from ipywidgets import FloatProgress
from IPython.display import display
f = FloatProgress(min=0, max=1)
display(f)
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    time.sleep(.1)
```

produces this text output:

```
FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=1.0)
```

Is there a setting I'm missing to get Jupyter to display these progress bars?

Comment: Are you having this issue in Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab?

Comment: Where are you running the cell? I get the `HBox()` message only in PyCharm, but it works fine when run in my Chrome browser.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru I got this issue in Jupyter Lab.

Comment: @Rafay Yes, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with plain Jupyter. Maybe someone should edit the question title and tags to reflect that so it's clear that the question and answer refer to Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The answer is in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/394#issuecomment-384743637).

The key is to ensure that you have the `ipywidgets` notebook extension enabled using the following command:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

For the old JupyterLab 2.0 you'll also need to [install the JupyterLab extension](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension):

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

For the old JupyterLab 2.0 installing the JupyterLab extension with the command above requires that you have [Node.js installed](https://nodejs.org/en/). The installer from the Node.js website includes `npm`, which is also required for the command to run properly.

When using JupyterLab **3.0**, the extension will be auto-installed together with `ipywidgets` when you install it with `pip` or `conda`. Node.js is no longer required for JupyterLab 3.0.

Comment: I tried this with a recent version of Juypterlab. The second command takes 10 minutes to run and doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Ok, it works (partially) if you re-start the kernel, close the Jupyterlab window, and come back. It only worked partially for me because the bar doesn't draw, but I can at least see my messages come up.

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag You may wish to add your experience with this fix on the GitHub thread I linked in my answer, or post a new question with your specific problem here on Stack Overflow, and link to this question for context. Given that it worked for a number of people, I think it's hardly fair for you to downvote my answer because it doesn't work in your specific case half a year after I posted this answer.

Comment: Worth mentioning that node,js is needed. I'm not using conda, therefore I've issued on a mac ' brew install node'.

Comment: I had also install npm. Otherwise the installation of the lab-manager failed.

Comment: wish this becomes auto installed and enabled with `jupyter lab`

Comment: In case you need to reinstall nodejs, you my want to uninstall the conda version (which is stuck to 6.13.1 at the moment)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not work for me. With node.js v12.16.1 and the ipywidgets extension installed, I still just get the plain old `HBOX(children=...)` static print out. I believe I already have the `@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` installed, and trying to install it again causes ~20 page traceback of a recursion error.

Comment: Running `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` (after running `pip install ipywidgets`) produces for me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgetsnbextension'`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgetsnbextension' with Jupyter 3.5.3

Comment: remember to refresh the browser

Answer (score 10):

An important consideration here is to have node version >=10.0.0 for this to work.
To check your node version use:

```
node -v
```

Also, you may have a version of node >=10 installed, but not selected. To check the list of installed node versions, you can use the node version manager `nvm` using:

```
nvm ls
```

In the example below, the selected version is 9.11.2:

```
->      v9.11.2
        v10.4.0
        v12.5.0
```

In order to fix this, I will have to run:

```
nvm use 12.5.0
```

Now, I can run the two commands mentioned by @Mihai:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

It should work now after refreshing the `Jupyter` browser tab.

Comment: note: Node.js is not needed for JupyterLab 3.0+; the extension can be installed with pip, and should auto-activate.

Answer (score 8):

Quick hack, if you don't want to solve it properly:

Run the command line version of `tqdm`, i.e. replace `from tqdm import tqdm_notebook` with `from tqdm import tqdm` and run `for i in tqdm(range(10000)): pass`.

This produced acceptable output for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Read all of it before executing a command:**

I followed all the instructions here, multiple times, nothing worked.

In my last try, I did:

Create new environment and install jupyterlab

From https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

Still it didnt work. Then as advised [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/issues/112), I did:

```
jupyter labextension install js
```

Restarted jupyter lab, tried the code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.IntSlider()
```

**And it finally worked. So I guess what was missing was to install js through jupyter labextension.**

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have node installed you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejsapt-get install -y nodejs
```

But sometime it is better to install via conda:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
 ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

And then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Reference: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html

Answer (score -4):

I found the solution provided by Bartosz Mikulski on his blog to be very simple and easy to execute: [How to display a progress bar in Jupyter Notebook](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-display-a-progress-bar-in-jupyter-notebook/)

```py
import time, sys
from IPython.display import clear_output

def update_progress(progress):
    bar_length = 20
    if isinstance(progress, int):
        progress = float(progress)
    if not isinstance(progress, float):
        progress = 0
    if progress < 0:
        progress = 0
    if progress >= 1:
        progress = 1

block = int(round(bar_length * progress))

clear_output(wait = True)
    text = "Progress: [{0}] {1:.1f}%".format( "#" * block + "-" * (bar_length - block), progress * 100)
    print(text)
```

You can also refer to [this Stack Overflow answer by ChristopheD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3160819) and ["3 Tips to Improving Your Data Science Workflow" on the Towards Data Science blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-tips-to-improving-your-data-science-workflow-71a6fb8e6f19).