# Display tqdm in AWS Sagemaker's jupyterlab

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

Does anyone nows how can we have python tqdm progress bar working on a Sagemaker Jupyterlab Noteook ? The tqdm progress bar is never displayed, components are displayed as their code.

Example :

```
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=5234.0), HTML(value='')))
```

I'm aware of the usual fix describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343134/jupyter-notebooks-not-displaying-progress-bars), but It does not work since trying to executing `jupyter lab build` will results in the issue describe [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2061)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for using Sagemaker Notebooks!

I got this working by following the instructions in your links.

Note: I had to use the Jupyter terminal instead of using a magic `!` from the notebook. There was a lot of output during the installation which slowed Jupyter down too much.

So in the terminal:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager > /dev/null
```

then:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

At this point you need to reload Jupyterlab in your browser. This is because the labextension build generates a new javascript bundle that you must reload to get.

Finally in the notebook:

```
!pip install tqdm
```

and then the example worked:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

example_iter = [1,2,3,4,5]
for rec in tqdm_notebook(example_iter):
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Hope this helps!

You should also try in a new notebook instance to ensure you are on the latest version of Jupyterlab.

Comment: I am using a Glue Sagemaker Jupyterlab notebook instance and cannot get this to work.  The prerequisite installs work using the terminal and the pip install works but isn't recognized when in a notebook.  I'm assuming it is looking in the wrong location but I have no idea where/how to find where it needs to be installed.  The below code works in a notebook but I don't want everything to be "local"


```%pip install tqdm
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
     for b in tqdm(range(10)):
        time.sleep(.5)
print("done")```

Comment: this works for me, remember to **refresh your browser** after running the commands to get it to work

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Between this and problems reading pickle files, I'll spend a whole day trying to get my notebook to run on Sagemaker.