# tqdm.notebook shows message with "HBox" instead of progress bar in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

This is the code I'm running in jupyter notebook:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(0, 100000)):
     continue
```

Instead of a progress bar, I'm getting the following message:

HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=100000.0), HTML(value='')))

If I use `from tqdm import tqdm` instead, it does work okay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebooks not displaying progress bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343134/jupyter-notebooks-not-displaying-progress-bars)

Answer (score -1):

You would need the ipywidgets jlab extension to be installed https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension