# using TQDM in Watson Studio Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience

I'm using Pandas, and I would like to use the TQDM progress bar in the notebook.

After loading TQDM:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
```

and applying a function to the Pandas Dataframe:

```
new_df = df.progress_apply(...)
```

I get as output, instead of the progress bar:

```
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=21375.0), HTML(value='')))
```

I already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343134/jupyter-notebooks-not-displaying-progress-bars) SO answer, but I'm not sure how to do it within a Watson notebook.

Comment: Consider using tqdm in text mode. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218684/5629418 This does not require a notebook extension that's disabled by default in Watson Studio on Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watson studio environments do not have "widgetsnbextension" notebook extension by default enabled.

In order to enable it, create a custom environment and enable "Esri ArcGIS" extension which will enables widgetsnbextension for ipywidgets when you start a notebook with this custom environment defintion.

[image]

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/faq.html#can-i-add-arbitrary-notebook-extensions

Once enabled, create new notebook with this custom environment definition.

[image]

Reference on how to create custom environment
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/customize-envs.html