# tqdm.auto progressbars does not display correctly and shows HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0), HTML(value=''))) instead

Tags: python, widget, jupyter, tqdm

I have some trouble with tqdm.auto

It worked correctly until few days ago, but it is not working properly now.

I think maybe some installation has messed up everything.

So, my problem is:

when I run this code:

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
```

Instead of progressbar, I get the following:

```
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0), HTML(value='')))
0   lr: 0.01
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='train', max=4.0, style=ProgressStyle(description_width='i…
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You may refer to the most voted answer of Jupyter Notebooks not displaying progress bars(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343134/jupyter-notebooks-not-displaying-progress-bars)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try to do this :

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

hope it works.