# How do I use tqdm to show progress bars when using read_csv in a Jupiter notebook using jupyterlab

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, tqdm

I want to read a huge csv using read_csv and pandas and I want to show a progress bar since it is taking too long. Is there a way to do this? I have just seen examples with loops.

Comment: What is wrong with using loops?

Comment: I usually don't need loops to use read_csv. I have found a way using chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You could abuse any of the number of arguments that accept a callable and call it at each row:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

with tqdm() as bar:
    # do not skip any of the rows, but update the progress bar instead
    pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=lambda x: bar.update(1) and False)
```

If you use Linux, you can get the total number of lines to get a more meaningful progress bar:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

lines_number = !cat 'data.csv' | wc -l

with tqdm(total=int(lines_number[0])) as bar:
    pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=lambda x: bar.update(1) and False)
```

But if you do not like for-loops, you may also dislike context managers. You could get away with:

```
def none_but_please_show_progress_bar(*args, **kwargs):
    bar = tqdm(*args, **kwargs)

    def checker(x):
        bar.update(1)
        return False

    return checker

pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=none_but_please_show_progress_bar())
```

But I find it less stable - I do recommend to use the context manager based approach.

Comment: With the first approach I get:

HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=1.0, bar_style='info', max=1.0), HTML(value='')))

but no progress bar. 

and the last approach just restarts my kernel.

Comment: This means you have not installed the extension that enables widgets (including the nice tqdm bar) in JupyterLab notebooks. For JupyterLab 3.0 just do `pip install ipywidgets` and restart JupyterLab (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343134/jupyter-notebooks-not-displaying-progress-bars).

Comment: I said I do not recommend the last approach ;) But seriously, if this causes a kernel restart, that is a bug and it would be very helpful (for yourself and everyone else) if you could report it to the repository of the kernel you use.

Comment: If you cannot get the nice widget working, you can always just use from `from tqdm import tqdm` instead of `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`