# tqdm notebook bar outputs text in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I am having a problem when using `tqdm.notebook` progress bar in Jupyter (version 3.4.4). When I launch a for loop, instead of the progress bar, I get the following text as output:

Input:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    a = 1
```

Output:

```
root:
    n: 0
    total: 100
    elapsed: 0.01399087905883789
    ncols: null
    nrows: 29
    prefix: ""
    ascii: false
    unit: "it"
    unit_scale: false
    rate: null
    bar_format: null
    postfix: null
    unit_divisor: 1000
    initial: 0
    colour: null
```

This started happening after I updated Jupyter to its latest version. The usual solutions regarding Node.js and ipywidgets (see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343134/jupyter-notebooks-not-displaying-progress-bars?newreg=03d2fdbbf0194141b9d96527db8ec8c5)) didn't do the job.

`tqdm` is also in its last version (4.63.0).

Comment: I have the same issue and this bug report cover the same issue https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1359 but not solution yet (I cannot downgrade my versions otherwise I am getting other issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran across this in a dockerized jupyterlab service.
This fixed it for me:

(Done in the Dockerfile):

1. `pip install -U jupyterlab-widgets==1.1.1`
2. `pip install -U ipywidgets==7.7.2`

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. However, I find it strange that I have to downgrade the versions of both packages for it to work... Is it a tqdm dependency problem?

Comment: Yes, currently downgrading ipywidgets should work as a temporary solution, until the relevant bug is fixed. It also worked for me with: `ipywidgets==7.7.2`

Comment: I had to run this too: `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`. Then, reload.