# tqdm showing progress bar properties instead of actual progress bar

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

When I run tqdm on colab, I get the expected progress bar output. But when I run it on my laptop, I get an output showing a description of the progress, bar but not the actual progress bar
[image]

What is going on, any advice on how to fix it? I simply installed `tqdm` with `poetry add tqdm` in a fresh poetry project. I am using a Mac.

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484988/tqdm-notebook-bar-outputs-text-in-jupyter-lab#73484988); someone is experiencing the same issue after the latest update

Answer (score 1):

tqdm have a specific tqdm class for notebooks:

https://tqdm.github.io/docs/notebook/

Comment: How does this explain or fix the described difference in behaviour between two machines? How does naming an existing class help with anything? At least demonstrate how that class can be used to solve the problem.