# How to print a horizontal gauge on Python output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that prints a float between -1 and 1, for example `-0.25`.

For visual reference, I'd like to print that on the output as a "gauge":

input:

```
print(float)
```

desired output:

```
-1 =======|==0==========+1
```

How would you suggest getting this done? Is there a library that can facilitate?

Comment: What do you want to show for exactly `0`?

Comment: great question... I thought `[0]` would work well

Comment: Use replace() for this

Comment: This might be related or helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar

Comment: Maybe you can find inspiration here: 
https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One relatively naive approach:

```
def gauge(x, width=20):
    pos = int((x+1) / 2 * width)
    g = ['='] * width
    m = width // 2
    if pos == m:
        sep = '[0]'
    else:
        g[pos] = '|'
        sep = ' 0 '
    g = ''.join(g)
    return '-1 {}{}{} +1'.format(g[:m], sep, g[m:])

>>> gauge(-0.25)
'-1 =======|== 0 ========== +1'
>>> gauge(-0.25, 50)
'-1 ==================|====== 0 ========================= +1'
>>> gauge(0.33, 50)
'-1 ========================= 0 ========|================ +1'
>>> gauge(0.0, 50)
'-1 =========================[0]========================= +1'
>>> gauge(0.99, 50)
'-1 ========================= 0 ========================| +1'
>>> gauge(-0.99, 50)
'-1 |======================== 0 ========================= +1'
```

Comment: that's fantastic @schwobaseggl, it does exactly what is needed, much appreciated!

Comment: Cheers, happy to help =)