# Compilation progress indication in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have been runing code which take over 8-10 hors for compiling. Is
there any way to print the progression of the compilation in a way
like 1% 2% ........99%, as we see in different applications? I could
have put such progression in one of the running loops, but in that
might not look convenient.

Comment: what have you tried so far? [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is a popular progress meter for loops, but may not work for your case

Comment: something like, k=0 ; while(k<N): .......... percentage=(k/N)*100; print(np.round(percentage, 3))

Comment: 'N_S = 100
k = 0
while(k < N_S):

 k = k + 1

 percentage = (k/N_S)*100
 print(np.round(percentage, 3)," % ")'

Comment: What 'compiling' are you talking about?  Do you mean 'completion'?

Comment: @hpaulj lets see my last comment, so I want to monitor progress of the code. I mean for larger values of N_S,  say, 1E10, the running time for the code will be large enough so I would like to monitor how much has it progressed which could be estimated by k*100/N_S and I may print the value at the end of each loop. But, that will not look convenient from representation prespective, as you it will keep onprinting lines after lines of percentage. So I would like to print it as 1% 2%....99% at a single point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)

Answer (score 1):

[tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is a popular progress meter for loops, and may work for your case

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

for value in tqdm(my_iterable):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(21):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    # the exact output you're looking for:
    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: Could you please explain, How do we decide the range of "i" here ?

Comment: 'N_S = 100
k = 0
while(k < N_S):

 k = k + 1

 percentage = (k/N_S)*100
 print(np.round(percentage, 3)," % ")'

Comment: Sir, could you please teach me how could your procedure be incorporated within this code ? Thanks.

Comment: It's just an example of how to show a progress bar. The value of progress depends on how you measure the compiling's progress. I guess you must compile a big number of files. then you can select when is a percent you decide among some files are processed. Then show the progress bar as above.