# Progress bar in Netmiko's send_config_set()

Tags: python, automation, progress-bar, cisco, netmiko

I would like to add a progress bar in my Python script on **send_config_set(rendered_template,cmd_verify=False)**.
That rendered_template is generated dynamically so it could vary in size and no. of commands can also be changes.
**How to add a progress bar so that I can show progress for `send_config_set()` command.**
Below is the code which I tried

```
animation = "|/-\\"            
for i in range(nlines):
    device_handler.send_config_set(rendered_template,cmd_verify=False)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + animation[i % len(animation)])
    sys.stdout.flush()
print ("End!")
```

it first executes the command without showing progress bar and when command executed then it is showing progress bar.

Seeking Help!!

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should end flushing by sending `sys.stdout.write("]\n")` after the loop ends.

```py
animation = "|/-\\"            
for i in range(nlines):
    device_handler.send_config_set(rendered_template,cmd_verify=False)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + animation[i % len(animation)])
    sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write("]\n")  # this ends the progress bar
print ("End!")
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar#answer-3160819) should perfectly fit your case.

The progressbar in your code is not really a progressbar, because commands are sent through `send_config_set()` which should be completed first, then the `sys.stdout.write("\r" + animation[i % len(animation)])` is executed. Also, using `send_config_set` sends the commands multiple times *(based on the `nlines` value)* because it's within a **"for loop"**! You can send commands one by one using `send_command` or `send_command_timing`.

Please check [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), it's an extensible progressbar library for Python that would be very useful.

Using `tqdm` is pretty straightforward. A complete demo using tqdm with Netmiko:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from tqdm import tqdm

device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "ip": "",
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "session_log": "whatever.log",
}

rendered_template = ["show ip interface brief", "show running-config", "show inventory"]
nlines = len(rendered_template)

with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:
    for i in tqdm(range(nlines), unit="command", desc="show commands"):
        output = net_connect.send_command_timing(rendered_template[i], cmd_verify=False)
print("Done!")
```

or use a list comprehension if `output` is not necessary to be returned.

```py
with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:
    # List comprehension
    [
        net_connect.send_command_timing(rendered_template[i], cmd_verify=False)
        for i in tqdm(range(nlines), unit="command", desc="show commands")
    ]
```

**Output**

```bash
show commands: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:12<00:00,  4.26s/command]
Done!
```

## Update August 17th, 2023

> netmiko==4.2.0 and tqdm==4.66.1

```py
rendered_template = ["show ip interface brief", "show running-config", "show inventory"]

with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:
    for command in tqdm(iterable=rendered_template, unit="command", desc="show commands"):
        output = net_connect.send_command(command, cmd_verify=False, read_timeout=60)
print("Done!")
```

```bash
show commands: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [01:10<00:00,  3.53s/command
```

Comment: This excellent just what my code was missing! =)