# python install command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, installation, tqdm

I get this error when I try to install **[tqdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)** package in python:

```
>>> pyp install tqdm
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pyp install tqdm
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I tried also to do it in the cmd (commands prompt) but still doesn't work

Comment: Hi there, do you mean `pip install` without the y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the installation command wrong, try this:

```
pip3 install tqdm
```

if you don't have pip3 installed [here is a guide](https://medium.com/swlh/solved-windows-pip-command-not-found-or-pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-dd34f8b2938f) for windows.

Comment: >>> pip install tqdm
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install tqdm
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: @LordFenny try it in the command line not in python prompt

Comment: you mean in visual studio, or commands prompt

Comment: commands prompt or any terminal in windows (cmd)

Comment: C:\Users\39349>pip3 install tqdm
"pip3" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.

C:\Users\39349>

""pip3" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 an executable program or batch file."

(btw it's in italian)

Comment: pip is the package manager it helps you install packages through the cmd you have to install it properly. check the guide link in my answer to solve that problem.

Comment: sorry, i'm new, where can i find it?

Comment: check my answer above there is a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 python -m pip install tqdm
```

Although I've not used that tqdm before.

Comment: >>> python -m pip install tqdm
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install tqdm
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Use command prompt to run it

Comment: already done actually

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: nope, still not

Comment: Type pip -version in your command prompt and press enter.

Comment: i found it from another person, but thanks also to you

Comment: continue like this