# Snowflake Python connector : Show progress bar for PUT/COPY command

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm currently using `Snowflake Python connector (2.6.2)` to move data from onPremise server to Snowflake.
My files are big, so I don't use `write_pandas()`, I prefer use `PUT` command to put parquet files in Snowflake internal stage, then use COPY command to move data from stage to Snowflake table.

(All Synchronous call)

```
# Put parquet files to stage
copy_into_stage = f"put file://{parquet_path} @{stage_name};"
cur.execute(copy_into_stage)

# Copy Snowflake stage to table
copy_into_table = self._copy_into_statement(table, stage_name, parquet_schema)
cur.execute(copy_into_table)
```

Everything works fine, but I really need to show some progress bar for my users.
Some dataset can take more than 1hours to upload ...

I saw that SnowSQL display some nice progress bar when you are moving data in/out to Snowflake, and I try to do the exact same thing.

Snowflake cursor object's execute method have some private parameters about progress bar :
`_show_progress_bar` or even `_get_callback`

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/19474a11d5e2f71f03cff49e639fff9b0eb16ad0/src/snowflake/connector/cursor.py#L575

- Is it possible to use build-in SnowSQL progress bar with Snowflake Python connector ?
- Does Snowflake return some metadata regarding the actual query's progress ? To use with callback function ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you may be able to do that using some of the Python functions but I don't think there is any sample for this use case from SF as such but this reference might be a good starting point: [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar?rq=1)

For the 2nd requirement, you can check the Query progress as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#checking-the-status-of-a-query