# show user 'processing' animation in python

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, busy-waiting

i just wrote an extremely long script that takes a list of URLs and runs a series of API calls, processes them etc.

Unfortunately for majority of the calls, response is empty (to give scale, i get result for ~100 / 4000 urls )

I'm wondering if there is a way to show in terminal (or powershell) some kind of animation to indicate that the process is still running. Currently - i have the standard blinking underscore.

I was thinking of something like alterating between \ - / |

i definitely don't want to trash the console with printing too much.

does anyone know if something like that is possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)

Comment: the simplest solution is to just display a counter. [*grin*] something like `13 of 666` works well and tends to be fairly fast. the built in PoSh `Write-Progress` cmdlet, tho, is notoriously S_L_O_W. it is the 1st thing one recommends _disabling_ when a script is reported to be "too dang slow".

Comment: issue is - i don't know how many iterations there will be :)
Depending on a user input - there might be one domain to take the links form, or might be a hundred,

In each of those domains you can find either a sitemap( containing URLs), a sitemap index ( containing a couple sitemaps) or nothing at all.
Than those all links get processed.

As only successful calls are reported - for majority of time, the idle looks stuck :)

So i look for somethign to show the user that their idle didn't crash :)
Unfortunately simple counter as i usually do that - won't do :(

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it in PowerShell.

```sh
$progress = '\', '|', '/', '-'
$i = 0
[console]::Write('Doing something...')
while($true) {
    $char = $progress[$i++ % $progress.Count]
    [console]::Write("$char$([char]0x8)")
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
}
```

Relevant docs:

- [`Console.Write(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-6.0#system-console-write(system-string))
- [Modulus `%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Index operator `[ ]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#index-operator--)