# The difference between sys.stdout.write and print?

Tags: python, printing, stdout

Are there situations in which `sys.stdout.write()` is preferable to `print`?

(**Examples:** better performance; code that makes more sense)

Comment: Which version of Python? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Honestly I'd like to know for both, although I have no experience with Python 3. Updated the question.

Comment: @S.Lott : asking for the basic differences between `sys.stdout.write()` and `print` (and/or why Python has both) is a perfectly reasonable question and does not need examples. OP did not say the command syntax was confusing.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

`print` is just a thin wrapper that formats the inputs (modifiable, but by default with a space between args and newline at the end) and calls the write function of a given object. By default this object is `sys.stdout`, but you can pass a file using the "chevron" form. For example:

```
print >> open('file.txt', 'w'), 'Hello', 'World', 2+3
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=print#the-print-statement

---

In Python 3.x, `print` becomes a function, but it is still possible to pass something other than `sys.stdout` thanks to the `file`argument.

```
print('Hello', 'World', 2+3, file=open('file.txt', 'w'))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

---

In Python 2.6+, `print` is still a statement, but it can be used as a function with

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

---

Update: Bakuriu commented to point out that there is a small difference between the print function and the print statement (and more generally between a function and a statement).

In case of an error when evaluating arguments:

```
print "something", 1/0, "other" #prints only something because 1/0 raise an Exception

print("something", 1/0, "other") #doesn't print anything. The function is not called
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `print` also appends a newline to whatever you write which doesn't happen with `sys.stdout.write`.

Comment: @Michael Mior: True, I've said that "it formats the inputs". Better answser would mention what kind of formatting. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Also `sys.stdout.write` is more universal if you ever need to write dual-version code (e.g. code that works simultaneously with Python 2.x as well as Python 3.x).

Comment: @MichaelMior You can suppress the newline that `print` appends with a trailing comma: `print "this",; print "on the same line as this"`

Comment: what do you mean by the fucntion is not called? " #doesn't print anything. The func is not called"

Comment: What's with the `>>`, or `__rshift__`, operator?

Comment: @bjd2385 The `>>` is not the rshift operator here but a specific "chevron" form of the `print` statement. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=print#the-print-statement

Comment: `sys.stdout.write()` also buffers the input and might not flush the input to the fd immediately.
in order to make sure that it behaves like the print function, you should add:

`sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: You can use `print(blah, end="")` to prevent a newline in print.

Answer (score 187):

`print` first converts the object to a string (if it is not already a string). It will also put a space before the object if it is not the start of a line and a newline character at the end.

When using `stdout`, you need to convert the object to a string yourself (by calling "str", for example) and there is no newline character.

So

```
print 99
```

is equivalent to:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(str(99) + '\n')
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the newline character!  This is the main difference between `print` and `.write()`, I'd say.

Comment: NOTE: `print` can be made to omit the newline. In Python 2.x, put a comma at the end, and a space character will be output, but no newline. E.g. `print 99,` In Python 3, `print(..., end='')` will avoid adding newline (and also avoid adding space, unless you do `end=' '`.

Comment: that's NOT true, `print` operation behaves slightly different in signal handlers in python2.X, i.e. print can not be replaced with sys.stdout in example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777610/why-print-operation-within-signal-handler-may-change-deadlock-situation

Comment: for better performance let's say `print(99)` is equivalent to:```sys.stdout.write(str(99));sys.stdout.write('\n')```

Answer (score 52):

Here's some sample code based on the book *Learning Python* by Mark Lutz that addresses your question:

```
import sys
temp = sys.stdout                 # store original stdout object for later
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w') # redirect all prints to this log file
print("testing123")               # nothing appears at interactive prompt
print("another line")             # again nothing appears. it's written to log file instead
sys.stdout.close()                # ordinary file object
sys.stdout = temp                 # restore print commands to interactive prompt
print("back to normal")           # this shows up in the interactive prompt
```

Opening log.txt in a text editor will reveal the following:

```
testing123
another line
```

Comment: Is there any way so that I can print to screen as well as write to the file?

Comment: @DeveshSaini: Yes, just overwrite sys.stdout with a proxy class that has at least a write() and flush() function. I wrote an example snippet [here](http://hastebin.com/owijihizus.py).

Answer (score 41):

> My question is whether or not there
>   are situations in which
>   `sys.stdout.write()` is preferable to
>   `print`

After finishing developing a script the other day, I uploaded it to a unix server. All my debug messages used `print` statements, and these **do not** appear on a server log.

This is a case where you may need `sys.stdout.write` instead.

Comment: huh? Are you sure this is a difference between `print()` and `sys.stdout.write()`, as opposed to the difference between `stdout` and `stderr`? For debugging, you should use the `logging` module, which prints messages to `stderr`.

Comment: Ya. Same is true with using `nohup` and redirecting to a `.out` file.

Comment: use of sys.stdout.flush() would help.

Comment: If you use `nohup`, by default all writing to `stdout` and `stderr` will be re-directed to `nohup.out`, disregarding whether you use `print` or `stdout.write`.

Comment: This answer is speculation and misleading/wrong, definitely should not have 40+ upvotes (as of this writing).

Answer (score 18):

There's at least one situation in which you want `sys.stdout` instead of print.

When you want to overwrite a line without going to the next line, for instance **while drawing a progress bar or a status message**, you need to loop over something like

```
Note carriage return-> "\rMy Status Message: %s" % progress
```

And since print adds a newline, you are better off using `sys.stdout`.

Comment: If print adds a new line why not just do print('message', end = '') instead?

Answer (score 9):

> My question is whether or not there are situations in which `sys.stdout.write()` is preferable to `print`

If you're writing a command line application that can write to both files and stdout then it is handy.  You can do things like:

```
def myfunc(outfile=None):
    if outfile is None:
        out = sys.stdout
    else:
        out = open(outfile, 'w')
    try:
        # do some stuff
        out.write(mytext + '\n')
        # ...
    finally:
        if outfile is not None:
            out.close()
```

It does mean you can't use the `with open(outfile, 'w') as out:` pattern, but sometimes it is worth it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you _can_ use `with` -- `def process(output): # ...` / `if outfile is None: process(sys.stdout) else: with open(outfile, 'w') as out: process(out)` (adding newlines where necessary of course). It's definitely not very clean, though, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.x, the `print` statement preprocesses what you give it, turning it into strings along the way, handling separators and newlines, and allowing redirection to a file. Python 3.x turns it into a function, but it still has the same responsibilities.

[`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) is a file or file-like class that has methods for writing to it which take strings or something along that line.

Answer (score 5):

It is preferable when dynamic printing is useful, for instance, to give information in a long process:

```
import time, sys
Iterations = 555
for k in range(Iterations+1):

    # Some code to execute here ...

    percentage = k / Iterations
    time_msg = "\rRunning Progress at {0:.2%} ".format(percentage)
    sys.stdout.write(time_msg)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: print(time_msg, end='')

instead

sys.stdout.write(time_msg)
sys.stdout.flush()

also works

Answer (score 5):

A difference between `print` and `sys.stdout.write` to point out in Python 3, is also the value which is returned when executed in the terminal. In Python 3, `sys.stdout.write` returns the length of the string whereas `print` returns just `None`.

So for example running following code interactively in the terminal would print out the string followed by its length, since the length is returned and output when run interactively:

```
>>> sys.stdout.write(" hi ")
 hi 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> sys.stdout.write(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
>>> sys.stdout.write("a")
a>>> sys.stdout.write("a") ; print(1)
a1
```

Observing the example above:

1. `sys.stdout.write` won't write non-string object, but `print` will
2. `sys.stdout.write` won't add a new line symbol in the end, but `print` will

If we dive deeply,

`sys.stdout` is a file object which can be used for the output of print()

if file argument of `print()` is not specified, `sys.stdout` will be used

Answer (score 2):

> Are there situations in which sys.stdout.write() is preferable to print?

I have found that stdout works better than print in a multithreading situation. I use a queue ([FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))) to store the lines to print and I hold all threads before the print line until my print queue is empty. Even so, using print I sometimes lose the final \n on the debug I/O (using the [Wing Pro IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_IDE)).

When I use std.out with \n in the string, the debug I/O formats correctly and the \n's are accurately displayed.

Comment: Do you know any reason why stdout should work better than print in this case, or is this anecdotal? Could you provide a minimal working example where this happens?

Comment: My thinking is that stdout works at a lower level than print.   I definitely had thread corruption as two print routines were fighting to feed through stdout.  Writing to stdout one from each thread removed the corruption for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877850/python-2-7-print-thread-safe?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 there is valid reason to use print over `sys.stdout.write`, but this reason can also be turned into a reason to use `sys.stdout.write` instead.

This reason is that, now print is a function in Python 3, you can override this. So you can use print everywhere in a simple script and decide those print statements need to write to `stderr` instead. You can now just redefine the print function, you could even change the print function global by changing it using the builtins module. Off course with `file.write` you can specify what file is, but with overwriting print you can also redefine the line separator, or argument separator.

The other way around is. Maybe you are absolutely certain you write to `stdout`, but also know you are going to change print to something else, you can decide to use `sys.stdout.write`, and use print for error log or something else.

So, what you use depends on how you intend to use it. `print` is more flexible, but that can be a reason to use and to not use it. I would still opt for flexibility instead, and choose print. Another reason to use `print` instead is familiarity. More people will now what you mean by print and less know `sys.stdout.write`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, if you need to pass around a function, then you can assign `os.sys.stdout.write` to a variable. You cannot do this (in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)) with `print`.

```
>import os
>>> cmd=os.sys.stdout.write
>>> cmd('hello')
hello>>>
```

That works as expected.

```
>>> cmd=print
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cmd=print
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That does not work. `print` is a magical function.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> What is the difference between `sys.stdout.write` and `print`?`

The best way I know how to explain it is to show you how to write `print` in terms of `sys.stdout`

Below I have provided three different ways to implement python's `print` function:

### Implementation 1

```python
import sys

def print(*args, sep=" ", file=sys.stdout, end="\n") -> None:
    # implementation One
    file.write(sep.join(str(arg) for arg in args))
    file.write(end)
```

### Implementation 2

```python
def print(*args, sep=" ", file=sys.stdout, end="\n") -> None:
    # Implementation 2    
    file.write(str(args[0]))
    for arg in args[1:]:
        file.write(sep)
        file.write(str(arg))
    file.write(end)
    return
```

### Implementation 3

```python
def print(*args, sep=" ", file=sys.stdout, end="\n") -> None:
    # implementation 3 
    it = iter(args)
    arg = next(it)
    file.write(str(arg))
    try:
        while True:
            arg = next(it)
            file.write(sep)
            file.write(str(arg))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    file.write(end)
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are there situations in which sys.stdout.write() is preferable to
>   print?

For example I'm working on small function which prints stars in pyramid format upon passing the number as argument, although you can accomplish this using ***end=""*** to print in a separate line, I used ***sys.stdout.write*** in co-ordination with ***print*** to make this work. To elaborate on this *stdout.write* prints in the same line where as *print* always prints its contents in a separate line.

```
import sys

def printstars(count):

    if count >= 1:
        i = 1
        while (i <= count):
            x=0
            while(x<i):
                sys.stdout.write('*')
                x = x+1
            print('')
            i=i+1

printstars(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the differences is the following, when trying to print a byte into its hexadecimal appearance. For example, we know that the decimal value of `255` is `0xFF` in hexadecimal appearance:

```
val = '{:02x}'.format(255)

sys.stdout.write(val) # Prints ff2
print(val)            # Prints ff
```

Comment: That's not what this is about. It would only happen in an interactive shell and because... `write()` did not add `\n` and returns (and interactive shell displays) function's return value (number of characters written), hexadecimal representation or any other content being displayed is immaterial.