# Why print operation within signal handler may change deadlock situation?

Tags: python, linux, signals, deadlock

I got simple program as below:

```
import threading
import time
import signal

WITH_DEADLOCK = 0

lock = threading.Lock()

def interruptHandler(signo, frame):
    print str(frame), 'received', signo
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        if WITH_DEADLOCK:
            print str(frame), 'release'
        lock.release()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interruptHandler)
for x in xrange(60):
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), 'main thread is working'
    time.sleep(1)
```

So, if you start that program and even Ctrl+C is pressed twice within 3 seconds, there is no deadlock. Each time you press Ctrl + C proper line is displayed.
If you change WITH_DEADLOCK=1 and you would press Ctrl+C twice (withing 3 seconds) then program will be hung.

Does anybody may explain why print operation make such difference?

(My python version is 2.6.5)

Comment: My guess is that print operation give change to handle new signal (without released lock)...

Comment: at least `global lock` is missing

Comment: Looking at the frame that is being interrupted, I notice that when it hangs, the signal is interrupting a different frame.  Also, changing the lock to be recursive stops the hang happening.  These tell me that it is hanging because the second handler is interrupting the first, then waiting on the lock that the first is holding.  The deadlock is because the first is waiting for the second to return, and the second is waiting for the first to release the lock.  When it doesn't hang, the frame being interrupted is always the same.  As to why this is the case, I'm still not sure.

Comment: I knew where it hung but I can't explain why it doesn't without print operation. Change Lock to RLock will broke security of critic section (as it's signal handler)

Comment: I've fixed code (removed function `main` and moved `lock` to global scope).

Comment: the surprising thing is that it doesn't deadlock without `print` on Python2 and indeed [it deadlocks even without `print` on Python3](https://gist.github.com/4063c1421499c09d3abc). Signal handlers must be reentrant (it is even more restrictive than thread safety). When the 2nd handler is executed the 1st handler is interrupted therefore it never releases the lock and the 2nd handler can't get it -> deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I think J.F. Sebastian's comment is the most appropriate answer here - you need to make your signal handler reentrant, which it currently isn't, and it is mostly just surprising that it works anyway without the print statement.

Comment: Yes, the last one comment of J.F. Sebastian's is the most I like anyway there is still no answer why removed `print` operation does not hung provided code in python 2.x.