# print() vs sys.stdout.write(): which and why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that creates output with `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stderr.write()`. Recently I've posted a couple questions about other aspects of the script and I've noticed that people posting answers seem to prefer `print('some text', file=sys.stdout)`. My primary concern with the output is simply that it can be piped by the shell, either into a file or as input to another program. Can someone please explain (or direct me to an existing explanation) the differences between `print()` and `sys.stdout.write`, the cases in which each should be used and the rational for those conventions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - The difference between sys.stdout.write and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"*Can someone please **explain** (or direct me to an existing explanation) the differences between print() and sys.stdout.write, the cases in which each should be used and the rational for those conventions?*"

Well I guess the silence you hear regarding Python3's print() function, is because there  practically is only one difference: Usage. Let me quote PEP-3105: [[1](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056154.html)]

The signature for `print()` is:

> def print(*args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None)

A call like:

> print(a, b, c, file=sys.stderr)

will be equivalent to today's:

> print >>sys.stderr, a, b, c

while the optional sep and end arguments specify what is printed between and after the arguments, respectively.

The softspace feature (a semi-secret attribute on files currently used to tell print whether to insert a space before the first item) will be removed. Therefore, there will not be a direct translation for today's:

> print "a", print

which will not print a space between the "a" and the newline.

So, quoting Guido van Rossum's discussion of the problem in 2005 [[1](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056154.html)]: There is a distinct non-linearity in print's ease of use once you decide that you don't want to have spaces between items; you either have to switch to using `sys.stdout.write()`, or you have to collect all items in a string. This is not a simple transformation, consider what it takes to get rid of the spaces before the commas in this simple example:

> ```
> print "x =", x, ", y =", y, ", z =", z
> ```

If it was a built-in function, having a built-in companion function that did a similar thing without inserting spaces and adding a newline would be the logical thing to do (or adding keyword parameters to control that behavior; but I prefer a second function); but with only
print as it currently stands, you'd have to switch to something like

> ```
> print "x = " + str(x) + ", y = " + str(x) + ", z = " + str(z)
> ```

or

> ```
> print "x = %s, y = %s, z = %s" % (x, y, z)
> ```

neither of which is very attractive. (And don't tell me that the spaces are no big deal -- they aren't in *this* example, but they are in other situations.)

---

Good question for a sunday morning down memory lane; *Why this apparent redundancy?* Because it is pythonically more correct to write higher-level code:

7th Zen of python: "Readability counts"