# What is the pythonic way to write strings to file?

Tags: python, file-io

What's the difference between using `File.write()` and `print>>File,`?

Which is the pythonic way to write to file?

```
>>> with open('out.txt','w') as fout:
...     fout.write('foo bar')
... 

>>> with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
...     print>>fout, 'foo bar'
...
```

Is there an advantage when using `print>>File,` ?

Comment: I think the first one. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Agreed. The second is primarily to make C developers feel at home.

Comment: In python3, the second will be `print('foo bar', file=fout)`, but the first one keeps the same.

Comment: You should take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3263763/1525683) for a proper explanation btw

Comment: These do different things. Even if you stick a comma on the end of the print statement, the soft-space feature will ruin your day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`write()` method writes to a buffer, which (the buffer) is flushed to a file whenever overflown/file closed/gets explicit request (`.flush()`).

`print` will block execution till actual writing to file completes.

The first form is preferred because its execution is more efficient. Besides, the 2nd form is ugly and un-pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way is the .write().

I didn't even know the other way, but it doesn't even work with Python 3.3

A similar way of doing it would be:

```
fout = open("out.txt", "w")
fout.write("foo bar")
#fout.close() if you were done with the writing
```

Comment: Python 3 changed `print` to a function, so the syntax is different: `print("some string", file=fout)`