# How to print the whole file line by line with `for line in f:`, including a possibly incomplete last line?

Tags: python

In Python, the syntax

```
for line in f:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

can be used to print a file.  Except it does not work when the file's last line is incomplete, does not end in a newline.  What to do then?

```
> echo -n > foobar.txt
> cat foobar.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in open("foobar.txt"):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
> ./foobar.py
>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't that work if the last line is incomplete?

Comment: What exactly do you mean *"doesn't work"*?!

Comment: The last line is not printed

Comment: What makes you think the last line isn't printed?

Comment: @user2357112 I show you above in the edited question

Comment: You're creating an empty file. There is nothing to print. Why do you think the nothing isn't getting printed properly?

Comment: Sorry everybody I got confused.  ID10T error code.  God please just let the earth open beneath me so I may fall in.

Comment: OK everybody, sorry again, THE REASON, why this was the question, is because, in a more complex example that does not work :)  I will post that as a separate question in a moment .   I basically thought "I will simplify it this way" - the simplified example does work, I got autosuggested.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Flush the output. `sys.stdout.flush()`. Otherwise, the output will only come out at a point that depends on the buffer mode; when printing to a terminal, that generally means when you write a newline, and you're not writing a newline. Depending on the situation, you may also want to add a newline if the file doesn't end with one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the line contains a newline character.

```
for line in f:
    if "\n" in line:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    else:
        sys.stdout.wrote(line + "\n")
```

I did some more research on sys.stdout.write() and it appears that you're going to need to force it to add a newline character to the end of strings that do not contain them. From what I've read ([Python - The difference between sys.stdout.write and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print)) `print` automatically does this for you then pushes the remaining string into sys.stdout.write. It might appear like a line in the file isn't being written properly if there's no newline character because it will be written to the same line on the console as the previous file's line. However, it should still be writing somewhere.

Comment: Yes but like I said in the question I want to print the file.  How to print the incomplete line.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Even if the line does not contain a newline character it should still print. Maybe you're experiencing some sort of data corruption? Could you post the error you're seeing in your question? Or maybe some sample I/O for us to read?

Comment: I posted the example for you

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the line ends with a newline:

```
for line in f:
    if line.endswith('\n'):
        # complete line
    else:
        # incomplete line
```

If you just want to print the line, you can just strip the line first:

```
for line in f:
    # Remove any trailing newline; `print` will add one automatically.
    print line.rstrip('\n')
```