# Is there a specification for a class's write() method?

Tags: python, object, methods

In python when you print, you're really just calling `sys.stdout`'s `write()` method.  Its easy to make your own custom class that gets written to

```
import sys

class MyClass(object):

    def write(self, astring):
        # do stuff

sys.stdout = MyClass()
```

What, if any, specifications are there for the `write()` method?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print) seems to indicate that it just needs to take a string input.  Are there any other rules or specifications as to what the method should accept and do?

Comment: if it's called like write and takes the same parameters as write then it's a duck.

Comment: I think that it is it - take a string and don't return anything - it should of course have side effects of impacting the return values of methods such as seek etc - and it should raise exceptions if required too.

Comment: i don't think any method is required to raise exceptions. The only requirement can be that if the exception is raised then it's of some predefined type.