# How do I save print statements when running a program in SLURM?

Tags: python, slurm

I am running a Python code that contains print statements via SLURM.  Normally when I run the Python code directly via "python program.py" the print statements appear in the terminal.  When I run my program via SLURM, as expected the print statements do not appear in the terminal.  How can I save the print statements to a file so I can check them as the program is running?  Below is my submission script that I submit via "sbatch submit.sh".  Notice that I've already tried two methods to write the output either to test1.out or test2.out.  Please let me know where I'm going wrong!

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -J mysubmission
#SBATCH -p New
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -t 23:59:00
#SBATCH -o test1.out

module load gnu python

python program.py > test2.out
```

Comment: Are you sure you know what directory the files are being created in? Try a fully qualified pathname.

Comment: I see test1.out and test2.out are both created in the directory where I run sbatch.  But these files are blank.  I'll try adding path names though.

Comment: Adding path names didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Force your output to go to stdout by using: `sys.stdout.write` instead of print. Consider using `logging` module.

Comment: I'll try that.  Is there no way to get print to appear in the output files though?

Comment: I've heard *nix can be tricky with that. Not sure really, I'm on Windows :(   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print

Comment: sys.stdout.write works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default, `print` in Python is buffered, meaning that it does not write to files or stdout immediately, and needs to be 'flushed' to force the writing to stdout immediately.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) for available options.

The simplest option is to start the Python interpreter with the `-u` option.

From the `python` man page:

> -u Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.
>   Note that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines() and
>   file-object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not
>   influenced by this option. To work around this, you will want to use
>   "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
python -u program.py > test2.out
```

And all your output will be saved to test2.out file.

Answer (score 10):

You can put

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

after the print statements of interest. Or since python 3.3

```
print("hey", flush=True)
```

is an option. Using unbuffered IO (with `python -u`) could reduce performance if you print frequently, especially on a shared filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions did not yield live output for me. (You need to flush print and sync the file change.) Here is a code that you can simply prepend to your python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import sys
import builtins
import os
sys.stdout = open("stdout.txt", "w", buffering=1)
def print(text):
    builtins.print(text)
    os.fsync(sys.stdout)

print("This is immediately written to stdout.txt")
```

That's it.

**Explanation**

Redirect stdout and write the file buffer after every newline.

```
sys.stdout = open("stdout.txt", "w", buffering=1)
```

Overwrite the print function and sync the flushed file also on the operating system side.

```
 def print(text):
    builtins.print(text)
    os.fsync(sys.stdout)
```