# How to print strings in a for loop without space in one line

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am wondering how can I print some strings in a for loop in one line without space between each other.

I know concatenating strings without space in one line, but outside of a for loop:

```
>>> print('hi'+'hi'+'hi')
hihihi
```

However, I have no idea how to do that in a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = ""
for i in range(3):
    s += 'Hi'
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by skipping `print` and calling directly `stdout`:

```
import sys
for i in range(3):
    sys.stdout.write("Hi")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Output result is `HiHiHi`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print) for a lengthy discussion of the differences between `print` and `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `print` function from Python 3 and specify an `end` string like this:

```
# this import is only necessary if you are using Python 2
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(3):
    print('hi', end='')
print()
```

Alternatively, `sys.stdout.write` does *not* add a newline character by default.