# Python (BeautifulSoup) - Output to text file not displaying all results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have created a Food Hygiene scraper that displays results based on a user inputted postcode. With the code I have posted below everything is working perfectly when run and results are outputted to console correctly.

I would like to get the results outputted to a text file though.

My code is :

```
import requests
import time
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class RestaurantScraper(object):

def __init__(self, pc):
    self.pc = pc        # the input postcode
    self.max_page =         self.find_max_page()        # The number of page available
    self.restaurants = list()       # the final list of restaurants where the scrape data will at the end of process

def run(self):
    for url in self.generate_pages_to_scrape():
        restaurants_from_url = self.scrape_page(url)
        self.restaurants += restaurants_from_url     # we increment the  restaurants to the global restaurants list

def create_url(self):
"""
Create a core url to scrape
:return: A url without pagination (= page 1)
"""
    return "https://www.scoresonthedoors.org.uk/search.php?name=&address=&postcode=" + self.pc + \
       "&distance=1&search.x=8&search.y=6&gbt_id=0&award_score=&award_range=gt"

def create_paginated_url(self, page_number):
"""
Create a paginated url
:param page_number: pagination (integer)
:return: A url paginated
"""
    return self.create_url() + "&page={}".format(str(page_number))

def find_max_page(self):
"""
Function to find the number of pages for a specific search.
:return: The number of pages (integer)
"""
    time.sleep(5)
    r = requests.get(self.create_url())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    pagination_soup = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "paginator"})
    pagination = pagination_soup[0]
    page_text = pagination("p")[0].text
    return int(page_text.replace('Page 1 of ', ''))

def generate_pages_to_scrape(self):
"""
Generate all the paginated url using the max_page attribute previously scraped.
:return: List of urls
"""
    return [self.create_paginated_url(page_number) for page_number in range(1, self.max_page + 1)]

def scrape_page(self, url):
"""
This is coming from your original code snippet. This probably need a bit of work, but you get the idea.
:param url: Url to scrape and get data from.
:return:
"""
    time.sleep(5)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result"})
    ratings = soup.select('div.rating-image img[alt]')
    restaurants = list()
    for item in g_data:
        name = print (item.find_all("a", {"class": "name"})[0].text)
        restaurants.append(name)
    try:
        print (item.find_all("span", {"class": "address"})[0].text)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        for rating in ratings:
            bleh = rating['alt']
            print (bleh)[0].text
    except:
        pass
return restaurants

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pc = input('Give your post code')
    sys.stdout=open("test.txt","w")
    scraper = RestaurantScraper(pc)
    scraper.run()
    print ("{} restaurants scraped".format(str(len(scraper.restaurants))))
```

The stdout command outputs to text file but the problem is that only half of the results are printed to text file.

Might it be that I have the stdout command in the wrong place causing it to stop halfway through? Without the stdout command all results are displayed via console correctly.

Many thanks to anyone who reads this and/or provides assistance to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded your code up and ran it.  It ran just fine.  I am not sure what your issue is, but it may just be that you are trying to look at the file while it is still writing.  When I looked at the file while the program was running it was blank.  When I looked at the file after the program had finished or was interrupted it was populated.

This happens because of [answer to stack overflow question explaining std.out and stdbuf in detail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182537/write-python-stdout-to-file-immediately)

If you need to print to the file immediately, consider using something like:

```
file_name = open('your_file.whatever', 'w')

# Then, wherever you use print, replace with:
file_name.write('stuff to write')

# Then, when you are done writing things:
file_name.close()
```

An alternative for similar write wherever you need to write to the file if you are not wanting to keep the file open and you are not wanting to write over your previous writes.

```
file_name = open('your_file.whatever', 'a')
file_name.write('stuff you need to add')
file_name.close()
```

Helpful reference: [explanation of std.out vs print.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an exception is raised in your try-except statement within scrape-page (i.e. rating doesn't have an 'alt' key), which will exit the whole for-loop. Try to debug by adding a print statement in the except code-block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try it when I am home to see if it gives me in. One question though, there are no exception raised when I run the script without the stdout line of code and all restaurants and ratings are displayed correctly, if it was a problem with an exception being raised should it not be raised without the stdout being present as well?