# sys.stdout.write() Acting different in interactive mode

Tags: python, stdout, interactive-mode

I have the code :

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\r Loading: {}".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

which works perfectly when I run `python3 dynamic_print.py`, but when I fire the up the interactive interpreter by typing `python3` and copy and run the above code into it, I get the output :

```
 Loading: 012
 Loading: 112
 Loading: 212
 Loading: 312
 Loading: 412
 Loading: 512
 Loading: 612
 Loading: 712
 Loading: 812
 Loading: 912
```

The last two digits `12`, are updated every time I run it (it was `11` when I ran it the last time). Why does it act differently and how to mitigate this?

Comment: In interactive mode, the results of expressions (if not `None`) are automatically displayed - and the return value of `.write()` on a file(-like object) is the number of bytes/characters written.  So your 12-character strings being written get followed by a "12".  `print()` doesn't have this issue, as it returns None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`12` is the return value of `write`, i.e. the number of characters written.  which in interactive mode is printed out, followed by a line feed

to fix this you could either indicate to the interpreter that you're not interested in this value (e.g. using `_ = stdout.write(s)`) or you could put everything into a function and hence keep it away from the REPL

I'd suggest doing the latter, e.g. something like:

```
def looper(n):
    for i in range(n):
        sys.stdout.write("\r Loading: {}".format(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

then invoke as `looper(10)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are getting different outputs because when you run `python3 dynamic_print` python compiles your file and generates bytecode for your python code (.pyc) then executes it in a python runtime.

When you use python3 on console it interprets the commands as you enter them. So you cannot clear the output generated in the python console just by . That's why you are getting the output each time in new line.

Another thing to note is the difference between the python3 `print()` and `sys.stdout.write()` is the return type each of them has. `print()` returns none and `sys.stdout.write` returns the length of string. Refer [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print).
The return type is the reason for getting extra **12**.