# Convert jupyter to python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to convert a string which represents a jupyter notebook to a string representing python program. And I met a problem that in jupyper, something like

```
data = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv")
data.head()
```

will output something, while in python program, we need to use print, like

```
print(data.head())
```

Therefore, I wonder if there any way to add 'print'.

I have a simple idea that parameters in python are consisted of 'a-zA-Z' and '_', so by checking whether the line consists only these chars, I can solve a small part of the problem. However, it's just not enough to deal with all situations.

Comment: I doubt this can be done automatically.  `data.head()` might be a legitimate method call that takes action without returning anything to print.

Comment: https://nbdev.fast.ai/ can be used for developing and publishing packages software using jupyter notebooks. Not sure whether this is what you are looking for

Comment: "I have a simple idea that parameters in python are consisted of 'a-zA-Z' and '_', " that is actually not true. Here are the details for what constitutes a valid identifier: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers but more importantly, as Tim Roberts notes, you cannot really do this in general unless you don't mind printing a bunch of useless stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this by writing sys.stdout to a text file in your program, if you want to keep the output of the entire program, whether it is a 'return' from a function or a print statement.

e.g. this answer demonstrates how to use stdout: [answer with code on how to log to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12182693/6848424)

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_jupyter_to_python(jupyter_str):
    python_str = ""
    for line in jupyter_str.splitlines():
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            if any(c.isalnum() or c == "_" for c in line):
               python_str += "print(" + line + ")\n"
            else:
                python_str += line + "\n"
    return python_str
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).