# Could I use \r to print a matrix over another matrix?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to show in console a matrix that starts out like this:

```
int matrix_1[2][3]= {{0, 0, 0}
                     {0, 0, 0}};`
```

Shown in console like

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

But then, just like in flash games where the Loading %1 updates to Loading %5 without scrolling down, I want the matrix shown in the console to update to this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

In code like

```
int matrix_2[2][3]= {{1, 2, 3}
                     {4, 5, 6}};
```

I guess I can use \r, but I don't understand how to superpose matrix_2 over matrix_1, I've tried it and it doesn't work. Do i have to use curse.h library or can I superpose the matrix in another way?

I'm new at this aspect of C programming..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there go up line character? (Opposite of \n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that easy to do that in C. You can have a look at [Ncurses](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html) library though. There [Moving the cursor](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html#cursor) section can actually help.

You can also use the following line right before the `printf` lines for printing the `matrix_2`. That will fulfill your requirement in *"not a good way"*, I think.

```
system("clear");
```

`Ncurses` will be better.

Comment: Actually "ncurses" is an orphaned blog on that site.  ncurses lives at http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html