# Replace input values in arraylist with a custom made class

Tags: shuffle

#### Replacing userinput with the card index

presented on a new row, and is not replacing the actual number the user typed. I've tried to put the letter and the number in the same arraylist but I have no idea how to display these.

Comment: You are calling deck,shufflecard which is shuffling your list<Card>. After that you are calling getcards(i) --> which is user input. as per the logic the card out put is correct.

Answer (score 1):

one thing I see you should replace `String secondCardLetter = card.getCardLetter();` with `String secondCardLetter = deck.getCards(i);` otherwise second card is same as first try that and let me know

Also recommend replacing `ArrayList<Card> card = new ArrayList<Card>();` with `List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();` please note the variable name change too since its a collection of Card(s). Initialize the deck with a loop

```
    char A  = 'A';
    int repeats = 2, numOfCards = 8;
    for ( int i = 0; i<numOfCards;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<repeats; j++){
            cards.add(new Card((char) ( A + i ) + "",i+1,""));
        }
    }
```

Please pay attention to your names as the to depict what the method may be doing. You `getCards` method takes an integer and returns the "Card", where as getCards shouldnt take any parameters and simply return the cards list you have stored. If you want to return a specific card, declare a method called `public Card getCard(int i)` notice the missing letter s as it shows this will return one card, and on the other hand `public List<Card> getCards()` method would return a List of cards, then that for loop would work.

Comment: what do you mean randomize the index number? I would shuffle the deck in the Deck Constructor

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the char cast, check now, you would replace in the deck constructor where you are adding firstCard secondCard etc replace that entire thing with that and it will add it, and I would still perfer the list being cards over card, hope that helps

Comment: Glad it worked, when you increase the points, replace the letter, add a method to Card setCardLetter where you replace the Card letter with empty string, then add a method in deck setEmpty(index i) which would set card letter of the `cards.get(i).setCardLetter("");`. So when you are increasing your points do `deck.setCardEmpty(data.getFirstUserInput());` then do it for second, let me know if you understand this. If every thing works, please accept the answer thank you

Comment: first thing is that your set method should be void unless you are using  the return values. and replace this in Card class `public void setCardLetter(String letter){ cardLetter = letter; }` if that doesnt do it update the code you have right in the question

Comment: its okay dont worry I understand let me know if it works or not

Comment: You can make sure by printing the cards before and after setting null

Comment: not sure how that loop works out but I would print it like `for (Card c: deck.getCards()){System.out.println(c.getLetter());)`

Comment: `deck.getCards()` would be a method that you would implement in Deck which would return the cards list

Comment: glad it helped. Again, even the it may not seem important, naming convention matters a lot. Give names that make sense. Even though it may be tempting to not care about them as the code will work eventually with or without proper names. It improves maintainability and readability.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking to do is to keep replacing the characters in the terminal output, without breaking the output into new lines right? i.e: a counter going from 1 to 100?

For that you need to use the carriage return character: `'\r'`

I think this is the line you are printing the letter of the card right?

```
System.out.println(format("%10s","\n[ " + firstCardLetter + " ]"));
```

Try changing this to

```
System.out.println(format("%10s","\r[ " + firstCardLetter + " ]"));
```

**edit**
Sorry what you have to use is the `\033[F` character, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n)

```
System.out.println(format("%10s","\033[F[ " + firstCardLetter + " ]"));
```