# How to overwrite multiline print in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

There is some code that displays the function process:

```py
all_nums = 100
counter = 0

def status(num, counter):
    print(
        f'Current number {num}',
        f'Numbers done: {counter}, all nums: {all_nums}',
        f'{(num/all_nums):2.1%}',
        flush=False, end='\r'
    )


for x in range(all_nums):
    counter += 1
    status(x, counter)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

It works. But I want to split this text on a line. When I add `\n` to any place everything breaks.

```
Current number 1, all nums: 100 0.0%
Current number 2, all nums: 100 1.0%
Current number 3, all nums: 100 2.0%
Current number 4, all nums: 100 3.0%
```

How can I overwrite console output in multiple lines?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I wrote it clearly: the code works fine until you add line breaks, after that it starts working like a regular print, i.e. does not change the line, but prints a new one.

Comment: Please clearly show the current output and the expected output, that makes it much easier for us to understand what you want

Comment: @Energya how i can do that? This function modifies the output string. Should I record a video to show how it works?

Comment: I ran your code and all output stayed resident on the same line. My environment is bash on Ubuntu. Could your environment be part of the problem?

Comment: @jhelphenstine do you run it with linebreak, for example here: f'Current number {num}\n', ?

Comment: I think @kshnkvn would like to be able to add line breaks between e.g. current number and numbers done and yet be able to clear those lines when the count increments. Right now, it works when the strings do not have `\n`

Comment: You may have to clear the console by `os.system('cls')` on windows and perhaps `os.system('clear')` elsewhere.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel so i must all time clear outp and print again?

Comment: `\r` (carriage return IIRC) moves the insertion point to the start of the current line which would be the last line if you have multiple `\n` (line feed) characters. So yes, you'll need to clear the console somehow to do what you want.

Comment: @kshnkvn I ran it as you wrote it, on both linux & windows, and it works as you intend it to -- all output stays on the same line.  edit -- at the end, the next command prompt line overwrites this one, but that could be addressed with a simple print() after your function call.

Comment: See this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/python-rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some ANSI escape codes to control your terminal: (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474509/8733066)
"\033[F" makes the terminal cursor go up one line, *3 is because there are 3 lines

```
def status(num, counter):
    print("\033[F"*3)
    print(
        f'Current number {num}',
        f'Numbers done: {counter}, all nums: {all_nums}',
        f'{(num/all_nums):2.1%}',
        sep="\n"
    )

# call this before the for loop:
print("\n"*3, end="")
```

Comment: Not working for me. The output is new every time, from a new line.

Comment: @kshnkvn what terminal do you use?

Comment: cmd, powershell, ubuntu bash in wsl

Comment: I set the "\033[F" to repeat 4 times, and this code will work well, in windows terminal application

Answer (score 0):

Simply update status function with:

```
def status(num, counter):
    print(f'''Current number {num}
Numbers done: {counter}, all nums: {all_nums}
{(num/all_nums):2.1%}''')
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F"*3) # Cursor up 3 lines
```

and

```
import sys
```

Answer (score -1):

```
all_nums = 100
counter = 0

def status(num, counter):
    print(
        f'Current number {num}',
        f'Numbers done: {counter}, all nums: {all_nums}',
        f'{(num/all_nums):2.1%}',
        flush=False, end='\r'
    )
    print()


for x in range(all_nums):
    counter += 1
    status(x, counter)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: I think kshnkvn is looking for his output to stay on the same line, and not exhibit newline behavior.

Comment: anyway this print all in new line

Comment: @jhelphenstine yes

Comment: When I ran the code as presented in the question, each iteration printed on the same line, overwriting the text from the previous iteration.