# How to dynamically update terminal output on multiple lines in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal

I am trying to write a program that will emulated a 20x4 character LCD screen by printing data dynamically to a terminal. Currently I am just trying to get the output to the terminal to work but I can't figure out how to print on multiple lines concurrently without using new line characters.

```
import time

i = 0
for i in range(0, 9):
    print(str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i), end='\r')
    print(str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i), end='\r')
    print(str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) +
          str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i), end='\r')

    time.sleep(1)
```

Currently this code prints one line of 20 characters that updates correctly but I need the additional two lines below it.
The expected output I would like is 4 lines of 20 characters each that updates dynamically.
Eventually, each line would just be one string for the 20 characters.

Comment: Did you try ```pyautogui``` ?? You can keep each character of the 4x20 LCD in a array arrays and then update the same

Comment: I have not tired pyautoaui. How would work for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using **f string format** and **docstring**.

Refer to the Official Documentation for F Strings(formatted string literals) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

The code should look like this.

```
import time

i = 0
for i in range(0, 9):
    print(f"""
          {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} 
          {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)}
          {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} 
          {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} {str(i)} """)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Please let me know if this help if it's not what you are looking for let me know so I can help you figure something more suitable for your needs.

Comment: wouldnt that just print 4 lines, then 4 lines under it, then 4 more lines?  not what OP is asking.

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood I'll provide another piece of code

Comment: no worries.  welcome aboard though.  dont think too much about different code, i really doubt it's very easy to do in pure Python without specialized libraries to print in place (something like what `top`  does in Unix).  unless there's a reverse linefeed, something that goes back up.

Comment: hah!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n  have fun!

Comment: Lol interesting

Comment: I read the referenced other question but not sure how that applies here, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting Rodrez's answer slightly:

```
import time

i = 0

goback = "\033[F" * 5  #  this "climbs you back up 5 lines" at the next
                       # iteration, output at same spot, like `top`


for i in range(0, 9):
    print(f"""{goback}
          {i} {i} {i} {i} {i} 
          {i} {i} {i} {i} {i}
          {i} {i} {i} {i} {i} 
          {i} {i} {i} {i} {i} """)

    time.sleep(1)
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474509 for where I got the weird characters from.

Comment: unfortunately, this prints out multiple new lines.

Comment: doesn't for me, on a mac.  linux would be same, most likely.  windows?  no idea - 33f is a character code for nix shell terminals I believe.  make sure you have goback at the correct spot and with the correct content.  you may also have to tweak `5` to be whatever the amount of lines your templates uses each time.  i.e. if 5 lines, then 5 33f back up.

Comment: I believe it needs to be in an ANSI terminal. Works well here on gnome-terminal on Linux.