# Python print output with updating lines instead of newlines, but more than one line

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose that I have a program whose output can be printed in a single line, and I want that line to update itself (inside a for loop, for example) instead of printing a newline. Then, for this I can use the carriage return (`print(output, end='\r')`). That's ok.

However, now I have a program whose output consists of 2 or more lines. I would like to have `2 lines` that are `updating itself`.

I tried something like this (as the most simplified example I can think of):

```py
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    sleep(0.5)
    print("first line:", i,end='\r')
    print("second line:", i+1, end='\r')
```

The expected output is to have a first line that updates from `0` to `9`, and a second line that updates from `1` to `10`, every 0.5 seconds. However it's not, it seems that the second line overrides the first one.

Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Comment: what is your expected output? Could you give an example output?

Comment: The expected output consists of two lines that are updating at every loop iteration. In the presented toy example, the expected output consists of a first line that updates from 0 to 9, and a second line that updates from 1 to 10. At the end of the loop, I would have only two lines, the first line with: "first line: 9", and the second line with: "second line: 10". In the toy example presented, maybe it's easier to think of it if one puts a sleep(0.5) at every iteration, I modified the program in the OP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite multiple lines in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For `.ipynb` output

Use `clear_output` from [IPython.display](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output) to clear the output before re-print .

```py
from time import sleep
from IPython.display import clear_output

TOTAL = 10

for i in range(TOTAL):
    sleep(0.5)
    clear_output(wait=True) # wait=True ==> Wait to clear the output until new output is available to replace it.

    print("first line:", i)
    print("second line:", i + 1)
    print("third line:", i + 2)
```

See [demo](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CaFypEO8nFYDiAeCzfpGEWX3PMaGeWSm?usp=sharing)

## For `terminal` output

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474509/14588461)

You can use `\033[F` to move the cursor to the beginning of the previous line

```py
from time import sleep

TOTAL = 10

for i in range(TOTAL):
    sleep(0.1)

    print("first line:", i)

    # if last index -> print without move cursor
    if(i == TOTAL - 1):
        print("second line:", i + 1)
    else:
        print("second line:", i + 1, end="\033[F")
```

Or potentially as:

```py
from time import sleep

TOTAL = 10
for i in range(TOTAL):
    sleep(0.5)
    print("first line:", i)
    print("second line:", i + 1)
    if i < TOTAL -1:
        print("\033[2F", end="")
```

If you want to move back `n` line you can use `\033[nF`.
ex: `\033[2F`: moving back to the beginning of `2` previous lines)

[image]

```py
from time import sleep


TOTAL = 10

for i in range(TOTAL):
    sleep(0.5)

    print("first line:", i)

    print("second line:", i + 1)

    # if last index -> print without move cursor
    if(i == TOTAL - 1):
        print("third line:", i + 2)
    else:
        print("third line:", i + 2, end="\033[2F")
```

You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't do what I expected: this code returns 11 lines as output, while it should be 2 that update themselves

Comment: Thanks @Liap but none of the code blocks in the answer works, altough it is helpful

Comment: @ElTitoFranki could you provide exactly the environment you're using? I have tested it on Jupiter and Google Collab as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have run it on https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/ and here is the [result](https://imgur.com/a/RrstgtJ)

Comment: I am using jupyterlab 4.1.1 in Windows 10. Your code doesn't work for me in Google Collab either, I don't know what could be the cause, maybe my OS? That my output in Google colab: https://imgur.com/a/bm277MO

Comment: I have now seen your updated answer usign clear_output, this works many many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe it will work:

```
from time import sleep
from os import system
for i in range(10):
    sleep(0.5)
    system('cls')
    print("first line:", i,end='\r')
    print("second line:", i+1, end='\r')
```

**EDIT:**

Usually `system('cls')` just clears the console maybe it will work for you.

Comment: I amb using jupyter lab, so the output is print in a notebook. Anyway, your answer only prints the second line,