# How do I prompt an input on two different lines at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I’m fairly new to Python, so go easy on me.

I’m trying to make the following inputs appear at the same time in the console

```
input("Please enter your feet: ")

input("Please enter your inches: ")
```

Desired output:

```
Please enter your feet: 

Please enter your inches:
```

At the same time for the user to enter.

Whenever I look up how to take multiple inputs at the same time,
I usually get a variation of answers stating to use the split function and to assign the input to two different variables:

```
x, y = input("Enter two nums: ")
```

But I feel that this would be confusing for the user, so I want to be able to prompt them two different entries at the same time on different lines.

Comment: It's most likely gonna be more hassle than it's worth. Get feet first, then get inches in next line.

Comment: What will it mean for the user to see two prompts at the same time?

Comment: how about `enter your height (e.g. 5'11")`? then parse the input

Comment: Or, just prompt for feet / inches separated by a space.  Then `feet, inches = response.split(' ')`. *Generally*, in computing, things do not happen ‘at the same time’. Each process is handled in turn.

Comment: Or even better: use SI units. ;)

Comment: You might dive into [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#curses-howto)

Answer (score 0):

Having a form where the user needs to navigate to separate lines to enter input is probably not the desired UI/UX. It is easiest to capture each in turn, or you could have them enter it in a single response and then parse that.

I've herein omitted error handling / input validation, which you will also need to do.

Example of two distinct inputs:

```
height_feet = input("Please enter your height in feet: ")

height_inches = input("Please enter your inches: ")

print(f"You are {height_feet}'{height_inches}\" tall.")
```

You could also combine the two on a single line with some delimiter:

```
height = input("Please enter your height in feet and inches, separated by a space (e.g., '5 11' is 5'11\"): ")

height_feet, height_inches = height.split()

print(f"You are {height_feet}'{height_inches}\" tall.")
```

Even simpler would be to use a single unit of measurement then convert it for display purposes. For example:

```
height = input("Please enter your height in inches: ")

height_feet = int(int(height) / 12)

height_inches = int(height) % 12

print(f"You are {height_feet}'{height_inches}\" tall.")
```

If you truly want two distinct inputs displayed at the same time, you are leaving the domain of a simple CLI and moving into the more complex realm of screen-painting / building a textual UI. [There are libraries that specialize in this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) but you will have to learn one and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without other libraries. If you really want this you might want to have GUI with the tkinter library

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI escape codes (see, e.g., the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n)). For example:

```
# just use print to output your questions
question1 = "Please enter your height in feet: "
print(question1)
question2 = "Please enter your height in inches: "
print(question2, end="")  # use end="" so as not to start a new line

# go back up a line (end of question 1)
print("\033[A", end="")
feet = input()
# move to end of question 2
print("\033[C" * len(question2), end="")
inches = input()

print(f"\nYour height is {feet}\' {inches}\"")
```