# How to refresh multiple printed lines inplace using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, stdout

I would like to understand how to reprint multiple lines in Python 3.5.

This is an example of a script where I would like to refresh the printed statement in place.

```
import random
import time

a = 0
while True:
    statement = """
    Line {}
    Line {}
    Line {}
    Value = {}
    """.format(random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), a)
    print(statement, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    a += 1
```

What I am trying to do is have:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Value = 1
```

Write on top of / update / refresh:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Value = 0
```

The values of each line will change each time. This is effectively giving me a status update of each Line.

I saw [another question from 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/python-rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console?noredirect=1&lq=1) however with the addition of the `end` argument in Python 3+ print function, I am hoping that there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do? Please provide a sample console output

Comment: Updated, hopefully it is clearer now, if not please let me know

Comment: so its actually  a single line you want to update ?

Comment: I am trying to update all lines in the statement

Comment: Ok so you're trying to only reprint a line that has changed, Dynamic screen refresh?? Using the default python IDE, this is not possible to my knoledge. There are ways to fake it buy it won't look as fluid.

Comment: but the first three lines are not changing.. #buffled

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I've updated the example to demonstrate the changing nature of each line.

Comment: In what way did you imagine `end` would help? I am a bit lost how that got a mention in your question and how oil thought it would work.

Comment: @jwpfox I tried end = '\r' * 4 however it did not update the whole statement, only reprinted beginning with the last line.

Comment: Yes. So how did you think it would help you do what you wanted to do? I am not being snarky I have to assume I am missing something you are trying to tell us that is passing me by. What you experienced with `\r` is expected behaviour but you seem to have expected (hoped?) for something different? Sorry, I am lost.

Comment: `statement` has a height of 4 lines. I want to reprint the value of `statement` again, inplace. So for example, a carriage return to the start of statement would work perfectly. Unfortunately `print(statement, end='\r' * 4)` did not take me back to the start of `statement`, only start of the last line.

Comment: Check this out `https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html` -- I think you want some thing like `ncurses`.

Comment: Can't by-pass   delimiter if used before. On python shell `\r` not work, use `print(statement, end="\n\n")` add a blank line for ending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear the screen each time you call `print()`, so that it *appears* the print is overwritten each time, you can use `clear` in unix or `cls` in windows, for example:

```
import subprocess
a = 0
while True:
    print(a)
    a += 1
    subprocess.call("clear")
```

Comment: This works only if he is working in the terminal. What if he is using the IDLE or some other interpreter?

Comment: This solution is not portable

Comment: Yes @BPL your answer is more portable :) although note `os.system` is deprecated

Comment: @Chris_Rands Deprecated? I didn't know that... I don't see it marked in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) though, where have you read that?

Comment: @BPL It says in the docs you link to that using `subprocess` module is prefered to `os.system`, also see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood correctly you're looking for this type of solution:

```
import random
import time
import os


def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

a = 0
while True:
    clear_screen()

    statement = """
    Line {}
    Line {}
    Line {}
    Value = {}
    """.format(random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), a)
    print(statement, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    a += 1
```

This solution won't work with some software like IDLE, Sublime Text, Eclipse... The problem with running it within this type of software is that clear/cls uses ANSI escape sequences to clear the screen. These commands write a string such as "\033[[80;j" to the output buffer. The native command prompt is able to interpret this as a command to clear the screen but these pseudo-terminals don't know how to interpret it, so they just end up printing small square as if printing an unknown character.

If you're using this type of software, one hack around could be doing print('\n' * 100), it won't be the optimal solution but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This works only if he is working in the terminal. What if he is using the IDLE or some other interpreter?

Comment: nice copy paste !

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I've never used that IDLE thing after working with python for many years so personally I don't care about it. Also, the OP didn't mention that requirement so the assumption is he's using some real tool

Comment: @BPL I use Eclipse and your method doesn't work. I was not specifying that it wouldn't work in IDLE, I was saying that it ONLY works on CMD or some other terminal...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html?highlight=ncurses) for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import curses
from time import sleep
from random import random

statement = """
Line {}
Line {}
Line {}
Value = {}"""

screen = curses.initscr()
n = 0

while n < 20:
    screen.clear()
    screen.addstr(0, 0, statement.format(random(), random(), random(), n))
    screen.refresh()
    n += 1
    sleep(0.5)

curses.endwin()
```